# Two Makes All The Difference - Cops

Tags: cops-and-robbers

> **NOTICE** - This challenge is now closed. Any new answers will be ignored and the accepted answer will *not* change

### Challenge

Write a valid program which, when just two characters in the program are changed, removed or added, completely changes the output.

The changed output must have a Levenshtein Distance of **15** or more from your original output.

The output must be non empty and finite. Your program therefore must terminate within 1 minute.

Your output *must* be deterministic, outputting the same thing each time you run the program. It also must not be platform dependent.

Any hash functions are ***disallowed***, as are built in PRNGs.
Similarly, seeding an RNG is not allowed.

After a period of three days, an uncracked submission will become safe. In order to claim this safety, you should edit your answer to show the correct answer. (Clarification: Until you reveal the answer, you are not safe and can still be cracked.)

### Formatting

Your answer should be in the following format:

```
# <Language name>, <Program length>

## Code

<code goes here>

## Original Output

<output goes here>

## Changed output

<changed output goes here>
```

### Robbers

The robbers' challenge is to find out which two characters you have changed. If a robber has cracked your solution, they will leave a comment on your answer.

You can find the robbers' thread [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466).

### Winning

The person with the shortest uncracked solution wins.

### Leaderboard

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>site = 'meta.codegolf';postID = 5686;isAnswer = false;QUESTION_ID = 54464;var safe_list=[];var uncracked_list=[];var n=0;var bycreation=function(x,y){return (x[0][0]<y[0][0])-(x[0][0]>y[0][0]);};var bylength=function(x,y){return (x[0][1]>y[0][1])-(x[0][1]<y[0][1]);};function u(l,o){ jQuery(l[1]).empty(); l[0].sort(o); for(var i=0;i<l[0].length;i++) l[0][i][1].appendTo(l[1]); if(l[0].length==0) jQuery('<tr><td colspan="3" class="message">none yet.</td></tr>').appendTo(l[1]);}function g(p) { jQuery.getJSON('//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/' + QUESTION_ID + '/answers?page=' + p + '&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=!.Fjs-H6J36w0DtV5A_ZMzR7bRqt1e', function(s) { s.items.map(function(a) { var he = jQuery('<div/>').html(a.body).children().first(); he.find('strike').text(''); var h = he.text(); if (!/cracked/i.test(h) && (typeof a.comments == 'undefined' || a.comments.filter(function(b) { var c = jQuery('<div/>').html(b.body); return /^cracked/i.test(c.text()) || c.find('a').filter(function() { return /cracked/i.test(jQuery(this).text()) }).length > 0 }).length == 0)) { var m = /^\s*((?:[^,;(\s]|\s+[^-,;(\s])+)\s*(?:[,;(]|\s-).*?([0-9]+)/.exec(h); var e = [[n++, m ? parseInt(m[2]) : null], jQuery('<tr/>').append( jQuery('<td/>').append( jQuery('<a/>').text(m ? m[1] : h).attr('href', a.link)), jQuery('<td class="score"/>').text(m ? m[2] : '?'), jQuery('<td/>').append( jQuery('<a/>').text(a.owner.display_name).attr('href', a.owner.link)) )]; if(/safe/i.test(h)) safe_list.push(e); else uncracked_list.push(e); } }); if (s.length == 100) g(p + 1); else { var s=[[uncracked_list, '#uncracked'], [safe_list, '#safe']]; for(var p=0;p<2;p++) u(s[p],bylength); jQuery('#uncracked_by_length').bind('click',function(){u(s[0],bylength);return false}); jQuery('#uncracked_by_creation').bind('click',function(){u(s[0],bycreation);return false}); } });}g(1);</script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><style>table th,table td { padding: 5px;}th { text-align: left;}.score { text-align: right;}table a { display: block;}.main { float: left; margin-right: 30px;}.main h3,.main div { margin: 5px;}.message { font-style: italic;}</style><div class="main"><h3>Uncracked submissions</h3><table> <tr> <th>Language</th> <th class="score">Length</th> <th>User</th> </tr> <tbody id="uncracked"></tbody></table><div>Sort by: <a href="#" id="uncracked_by_length">length</a> <a href="#" id="uncracked_by_creation">creation</a></div></div><div class="main"><h3>Safe submissions</h3><table> <tr> <th>Language</th> <th class="score">Length</th> <th>User</th> </tr> <tbody id="safe"></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: @BetaDecay How do you define a hash function?

Comment: Can't one brute force every possible change?

Comment: @xnor Theoretically, but the number of possibilities increases hugely as the program length increases and so may take a long time

Comment: @isaacg A function which finds the [hash value](http://pinpointlabs.com/2010/12/what-is-a-hash-value/) of an object

Comment: @BetaDecay I think the problem might be that the shortest uncracked solution is the winner but the shortest solutions are also the easiest to brute force

Comment: I so want to do a very long brainfuck one just to laugh while people get crazy..

Comment: @RedPanda Go for it ;)

Comment: I guess changing the place of a character counts as one removed + one added?

Comment: @RedPanda Yes, I would think so

Comment: Just to clarify, must the program always have the same output if any two characters are changed other than the chosen two? Or just that the desired new output is only achieved by changing those two characters?

Comment: @StephenTG Not the OP, but I would assume that as long as you can get the same output, the crack is valid even if it's not the exact same changes as the poster. Or at least that's the case with most other cops and robbers.

Comment: Do you have to change 2 characters? Can I only change 1 character if I want to?

Comment: @BetaDecay How long until submissions are safe?

Comment: @Dennis One day

Comment: @muddyfish No, it has to be 2 characters

Comment: @BetaDecay So, If a submission goes uncracked for 24 hours, should the poster post the solution to make it safe? If so, can you add that to the OP?

Comment: @isaacg I decided to change the safe date to three days

Comment: @StewieGriffin Nope

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes, of course :) have a look at isaacg's many answets

Comment: Would it be possible to put the leaderboard code on fewer lines so it takes up less visual room?

Comment: The brainfuck code by kurousagi was cracked a long time ago... Someone should update it

Comment: @AboveFire Until Kurousagi acknowledges the crack, we can't make the snippet change unfortunately

Comment: @AboveFire Was it cracked with the correct unprintables? Last we heard he was going to find a way to add the unprintables or something to that effect, then, radio silence.

Comment: Brute forcing has complexity O(N^2), although the constant can admittedly be pretty large.

Comment: "No, it has to be 2 characters" In that case, would [adding a single space](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54612/7951) plus one "real" change be allowed? In most programming languages whitespace is insignificant, so one can easily go from "2 characters" to "1 [effective] character" if this is allowed.

Comment: I want to do this in Marbelous.

Comment: "No, it has to be 2 characters" - There's a woolly thing.
One removal, and one adjacent insert effectively changes one char.
One change and one adjacent removal effectively removes one char.
One add and one adjacent replacement effectively adds one char.
So, at least until rules are clarified to exclude this loophole, I'd argue that you can effectively affect only one character, so long as you CALL it two characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CJam, 13 bytes (safe)

```
J{m!_)mQ%2b}/
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=J%7Bm!_)mQ%252b%7D%2F)

#### Original output

```
000010010101001010001101111000111011100110100100001011101101010100011111110010010010001111111111010000010011001110001010011111000010001001110111100000010110000010000111011011110101110010000011100111100
```

#### Modified output

```
11101101100011110001011010000100111011000010011101100000001010100111011010011011010111101000000011101111100000000110001000111110110110101111110100101110000101110100110011110000010101110
```

#### Solution

```
J{m!_)ci%2b}/
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=J%7Bm!_)ci%252b%7D%2F)

#### How it works

This takes advantage of how CJam implicitly prints the entire stack after executing the program.

Simply dumping the base-2 representations of a few integers on the stack causes them to be printed without any separator, so it should be hard to figure out where one of them begins and another one ends.

The original code does the following:

```
J{   e# For each I from 0 to 18, do the following:
  m! e#   Calculate the factorial of I.
  _) e#   Push a copy and add 1.
  mQ e#   Compute the result's integer square root.
  %  e#   Calculate the residue of the factorial divided by the square root.
  2b e#   Push the array of base 2-digits of the resulting integer.
}/   e#
```

As @AndreaBiondo notes in the comments, the binary representations of **0!** to **8!** can be found at the beginning of the output (spaces added for clarity):

```
1 1 10 110 11000 1111000 1011010000 1001110110000 1001110110000000
```

The intended change was to replace `mQ` with `ci`, which takes the integer modulo 65536, using 16-bit character arithmetic (casting to an unsigned 16-bit character, then back to integer).

I hoped the idea of using `c` to replace a mathematical operator would be obscure enough.

Comment: Wow. How do you come up with this?

Comment: I tried to crack this for quite a while. I figured out part of the modified pattern, but I was missing something. It's safe now I guess.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo It is now. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Dennis I had figured out that `_)mQ` needed to be changed to an `f(x!)` such that `f(x!) > x!` for `x <= 8` and `f(x!) < x!` for `x >= 9`, because `x!` was obviously being modulo'ed by a number that left the factorials from 0 to 8 intact in the output. I didn't notice `9!` was the first factorial bigger than `2^16`. Very nice challenge anyway.

Answer (score 39):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54637/6741)

## Shakespeare, 1721 bytes

I tried a Shakespeare answer. It is not short, and I had difficulties to change the output with only 2 characters, but I think I succeeded quite well. Good Luck everybody. As a side note, I used the "compiler" available at [this](https://github.com/drsam94/Spl/) address and **it may not work with another one.** (it does not work with the online interpreter) The output does not contain any unprintable characters.

### Code

```
The Hidden Change.

Helen, a young woman with a remarkable patience.
Helena, a likewise young woman of remarkable grace.
Claudio, a remarkable man much in dispute with Claudius.
Claudius, the flatterer.
The Archbishop of Canterbury, the useless.


          Act I: Claudius's insults and flattery.

          Scene I: The insulting of Helen.

[Enter Claudius and Helen]

Claudius:
 Thou art as hairy as the sum of a disgusting horrible fatherless 
 dusty old rotten fat-kidneyed cat and a big dirty cursed war.
 Thou art as stupid as the product of thee and a fat smelly 
 half-witted dirty miserable vile weak son.
 
[Exeunt]

          Scene II: The complimenting of Helena.
          
[Enter Claudio and Helena]

Claudio:
 Thou art the sunny amazing proud healthy peaceful sweet joy.
 Thou art as amazing as the product of thee and the pretty
 lovely young gentle handsome rich Hero. Thou art as great 
 as the sum of thee and the product of a fair golden prompt good honest 
 charming loving noble king and a embroidered rich smooth golden angel.
 
[Exeunt]

          Scene III: The insulting of Claudio
          
[Enter Claudius and Helen]

Helen:
 Thou art as stupid as the sum of the sum of thee and a cat and me.
[Exit Helen]

[Enter Claudio]

Claudius:
 Thou art as stupid as the sum of thee and the product of the 
 product of me and Helen and Helena
 
[Exeunt]

          Scene IV: The Final Countdown
          
[Enter The Archbishop of Canterbury and Claudius]

Claudius:
 Thou art the sum of you and a cat.

The Archbishop of Canterbury:
 Am I better than a fine road?
 
Claudius:
 If not, let us return to the insulting of Claudio.
 
[Exit The Archbishop of Canterbury]

[Enter Claudio]

Claudius:
 Open your heart!
 Open your heart!
[Exeunt]
```

### Original Output

```
11324620811132462081
```

### Changed Output

```
11
```

Comment: Truly marvelous. This story brought tears to my eyes.

Comment: @AlexVanLiew It took me a really long time to write. It is my masterpiece!

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54637/6741)!

Comment: Very Nice answer

Answer (score 24):

## J, 76 bytes (safe)

### Code

```
,:|.,.<,:>><|.,:>,.<|.>,:<<|.>|.,:,.<,.<,:,.<,:>|.<,:>,.|.<,:,.|.<<,:>126$a.
```

### Original Output

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│
││┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐││
│││┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│││
││││┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐││││
│││││     ┌┬┐├┼┤└┴┘│─ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}│││││
││││└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘││││
│││└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘│││
││└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘││
│└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘│
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

### Changed output

```
┌──────────────────────┐
│┌────────────────────┐│
││┌──────────────────┐││
│││┌────────────────┐│││
││││┌──────────────┐││││
│││││┌───────────┬┐│││││
││││││0 0 0 0 0 0│││││││
│││││└───────────┴┘│││││
││││└──────────────┘││││
│││└────────────────┘│││
││└──────────────────┘││
│└────────────────────┘│
└──────────────────────┘
```

## EDIT: Solution `{:` added (shown between `###`)

```
,:|.,.<,:>><|.,:>,.<|.>,:<<|.>|.,:,.<,.<,:,.<,###{:###:>|.<,:>,.|.<,:,.|.<<,:>126$a.
```

Makes use of the monad [`{::` Map](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/curlylfcoco). Most of the rest of the code is useless garbage.

Comment: Note that I could certainly extend the code by a ridiculous amount of characters to make it harder to find the spot(s) where the two characters need to be added/removed/changed

Comment: I think it's been 3 days for this one, so if you post the answer, you're safe.

Comment: @isaacg Correct, edited the answer

Answer (score 12):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54566/6828)

## Ruby, 14

### Code

```
x=9;puts x*9*9
```

### Original Output

```
729
```

### Changed output

```
99999999999999999
```

Comment: This looks so innocent. I've tried and I've tried, but I don't know where to get the 17 from...

Comment: I thought it was 18 9s, so I was going for something like `'99'*2`. `wc`, you betrayed me!

Comment: @AlexVanLiew 18 would be easy. Blame your shell for appending a linefeed.

Comment: @Dennis How would you do it with 18? I couldn't figure it out (but I also don't know Ruby).

Comment: @AlexVanLiew `x=?9;puts x*2*9`

Comment: @Dennis Aha, does `?` mean "start of character literal"? I knew there had to be something in there for that, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54566/16941)

Answer (score 12):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54534)

## Bash, 15 bytes

```
echo {{{1..9}}}
```

#### Original output

```
{{1}} {{2}} {{3}} {{4}} {{5}} {{6}} {{7}} {{8}} {{9}}
```

#### Modified output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54534/42620)

Comment: Well done. This lasted longer than I thought it would.

Answer (score 10):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54533/20080)

## Python 2, 43 bytes

### Code

```
print (sum(range(054321)*9876)*87654)/01234
```

### Original Output

```
334960491355406
```

### Changed output

```
222084148077792
```

The Levenshtein Distance is 15 exactly. Both the original and the changed run under 1 minute on my computer.

Comment: I've edited your post to reflect that this is a Python 2-specific submission, due to the missing parentheses for `print` and the multiplication of `range` by an integer. However, I seem to be getting `MemoryError`s from the large list...

Comment: Sorry, yes it is python 2, the most memory it uses on my computer is 1.61GB, is that really too much?

Comment: No, it's all good. My computer's just a bit low of memory and I wasn't sure how much it used.

Comment: Since this isn't code golf, you could reduce the memory load by using `xrange` instead of `range` and I believe `itertools` has a generator-builder that repeats a sequence `x` number of times.

Comment: @AlexVanLiew But the scoring *is* code-golf in a sense, shortest uncracked. Having said that though, there's an unnecessary space and pair of parens... *or are they necessary?* ;)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice shortest uncracked. Sure.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't notice that you could change, add, *or* remove two characters. I was working on this but ugh, I don't want to play with numbers like that.

Comment: IMO this answer seems kind of not interesting **if** this relies only on changing the numbers involved (we don't know if this is the case), because in that case you can probably do shorter and the only way it will ever get cracked is just by brute force, not cleverness.

Comment: Changing `range` to `xrange` breaks it on my computer - py2.7. (Thats the original, i didnt test it with the changed). It might not for py3 but i cant tell if the changed stuff will be the same in py3 because i dont have it

Comment: @muddyfish: `xrange` returns a generator, so multiplying it by a number won't work in py2.7. However, you can achieve the same result with one more character: `print (sum(xrange(054321))*9876*87654)/01234` (note the moved paren). It also computes almost instantly on a weak machine I was testing on, whereas prior it threw `MemoryError`. You don't have to change it by any means (and for all we know it breaks the changed version) but if it still works fine it would help a bit.

Comment: The octal numbers are clever, though.

Comment: No, it doesn't break it by making the change you made. By changing (or adding/removing) 2 chars in that version, you can still get the same output

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54533/20080) That was a fun one!

Answer (score 10):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54489/20080)

## Prolog, 10 bytes

### Code

```
X is 1/42.
```

### Original Output

```
X = 0.023809523809523808.
```

### Changed output

```
X = -2.
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54489/21487)

Comment: For some reason I totally overlooked the fact that this can also be solved like this: `X is 1//4-2.`, which is a lot easier to see than my original solution that @sp3000 cracked...

Answer (score 8):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54515/20080)

## BrainFuck , 504 bytes

No one should ever need to analyse a brainfuck code.
This is a modified version of an earlier code, but any change in a Brainfuck code make a big difference in the output. I use the Interpreter at http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html to test my code. Good Luck !

## Code

```
++++++++++[->++++++++<]>>++++++[-<---------->]<-------[----------->>>-<<+<[-->->+<<]]>>>+<<>>>+++[->++++++++++<]>++.<+++++++++[->>>>>>>++++++++++<+++++<++++++++++++++<++++++++++<+++++<++++++++++<<]++++++++++>>+++++...>++>++>-->+>++++<<<<<<<.<<<[->>>>>>.<<>>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<<>>>.<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<...>.<<<<<<]>[->>>>>.<<...>>>.<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<...>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<...>.<<<<<]>[->>>>.<<>>>>>>.<<<<<<..>>>.<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<>>>>>>.<<<<<<.>>>>>>.<<<<<<>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<...>.<<<<]
```

## Original Output

```
 ___
/   \
|   |
\___/
```

## Changed Output

```
}}}\}}}|.}}}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\\}}|.}.|///\
```

Note: The Changed Output contains several STX(ASCII 2) and EOT(ASCII 4) characters

Here is the version with ASCII codes in parenthesis instead of unprintable characters:

```
(2)}}}(2)\}}}|(2).}}}.(2)|///\\(4)}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)|///\\(4)}}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)///\\(4)}}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)|///\\(4)}}(2).(4)}(4).(2)|///\\(4)}}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)|/(4)/\\(4)}}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)|///\\(4)}}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)|///\\(4)}}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)|///\\(4)}}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)|///\\(4)}}|(2).(4)}(4).(2)|///\
```

Comment: You are evil. But i will find it!

Comment: @RedPanda My code does have a structure. At least it's not random! Good luck!

Comment: are there any unprintables in the output?

Comment: @proudhaskeller Yes sorry about that, I'll edit the post, there is a bunch of  character STX(ASCII 2) and EOT(ASCII 4)

Comment: but where are they? i don't have the information

Comment: @proudhaskeller I am working on it right now :)

Comment: your changed code without the unprintable characters starts with "}}}\}}}", but the one with them starts with "(2)}}}(2)}}}", mssing the "\". can you double check this? there may be errors in other parts too.

Comment: @proudhaskeller I tried to use bold to make the chars clearer, but "\" does not appear in a citation. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26871/discussion-between-proud-haskeller-and-abovefire).

Comment: cracked http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54515/20370

Answer (score 8):

## [cracked](/a/54644)

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica or WolframAlpha), 3 bytes

### Code

```
8.!
```

### Original Output

```
40320.
```

### Changed output

```
2.67182 - 0.891969 I
```

For those trying it on WolframAlpha the result shows up as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I deleted my previous answer because it worked only on Mathematica and not in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8.!). That put robbers behind a paywall (instead of the deserved bars), which wasn't fair.

Comment: Cracked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54644#54644

Comment: @abligh Nice! :)

Comment: What was the answer of the other one? I am very curious.

Answer (score 7):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54514/20080)

## CJam, 8 characters

### Code

```
"~f":i:#
```

### Original output

```
17290024234092933295664461412112060373713158853249678427974319674060504032816100667656743434803884485234668769970047274563123327020396104330878852891146011372048615474145637592955298601510765168228550988848615653376
```

### Changed output

Output after modification is [here](https://bpaste.net/raw/f449928d9870). Both take under a minute on my 2GHz laptop.

### Explanation

People seem amazed at how this works. The code works like this:

```
"~f"       Push a string
    :i     Convert to a list of bytes [126 102]
      :#   Fold with # (power)
```

This calculates 126^102. The solution was:

```
"}\t~f"
       :i     Convert to a list of bytes [125 9 126 102]
         :#   Fold with # (power)
```

This calculates ((125^9)^126)^102, which is hundreds of thousands of digits long.

Comment: This is criminal.

Comment: What the... I really wanna know how this works! ;)

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54514)

Comment: @BetaDecay I could explain how the original works but not Dennis's version. I wonder how Mauris meant it to be solved...

Comment: Holy bananas!  WTF!

Answer (score 7):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54730/20080)

## Pyth, 8 bytes

### Code:

```
%CG^3y21
```

### Initial Output:

```
51230235128920219893
```

### Changed Output:

```
58227066
```

Comment: The changed output equals `CG mod (2^21 * 28)`. I don't know Pyth, so I can't see how to change `(3 ^ (2 * 21))` into that...

Comment: Also, `CG` equals `sum(256**n * (122-n) for n in range(26))`.

Comment: The changed output also equals `CG mod (2^21 * 28 * 2*n)`, where `1 <= n <= 4`, as well as for `n=6` and `n=12`. Also, `CG` is just the lowercase alphabet interpreted as a base 256 number. I wonder if there's another modulo with base 3?

Comment: `%CG^2 26` or `%CG^4y13`, but both have a distance of 3...

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54730)

Answer (score 7):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54550/21654)

## MATLAB / OCTAVE, 7 bytes

## Code:

```
cos(pi)
```

## Original output:

```
ans =

     -1
```

## Changed output:

```
ans =

   1.5708 - 0.8814i
```

This gives a Levenshtein distance of exactly 15.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54550/21654)

Comment: The big tipoff for me was noticing that the real part of your changed output is pi/2. From there, it wasn't hard to guess the solution.

Answer (score 6):

## GolfScript, 15 bytes (safe)

### Code

`10,{1+3?}%{*}*]`

### Changed code

`107,{1+3?}%{^}*]`

### Original Output

`47784725839872000000`

### Changed output

`557154`

Explainations:

```
10,             # numbers from 0 to 10
   {1+3?}%      # add one and raise to the cube. (%=for each)
          {*}*] # take the product and place it in a list(useless)`
```

Changed code

```
107,             # numbers from 0 to 107
    {1+3?}%      # add one and raise to the cube. (%=for each)
           {^}*] # xor them and place it in a list(useless)
```

Comment: I do believe this is safe now, so if you'd like to edit your post

Comment: @BetaDecay I am!

Answer (score 6):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54574/21487)

## Python 2, 58 bytes

### Code

```py
R=range(01234);print sum(m<<min(m,n)for m in R for n in R)
```

### Original Output

```
2444542772018013876036977350299418162656593659528311114655474359757543862791958572561591492595632222632192542272836836649846934427359810217936317967768095940470375690509652583392001888886352103127515963142
```

### Changed output

```
4669
```

That 15 distance rule sure made things tricky. I hope this goes well.

Comment: The fact that 4669 = 667*7 and that the last element of range(01234) is 667 is suspicious to me...

Comment: If you print out `[m<<min(m,n)for m in R for n in R]` in the interpreter, you get some really spooky white-noise esque patterns.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54574/25180)

Answer (score 6):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54641#54641)

## Python 2, 50 bytes

Original Code:

```
'~'*sum([(x,y)[x%2]for x in[y for y in range(8)]])
```

Original Output:

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
```

Modified Output:

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
```

Not overly short, and maybe not too hard, I don't really know. I'll try to come up with something better soon.

Comment: Is that 40 tildes and then 19 tildes? And I suppose this is run in the interpreter?

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54641/19349), I think

Comment: Not cracked yet. [Here's what I've done so far](http://repl.it/BBeB), but I know I'm not doing it quite right (since more then 2 chars are changed sometimes. I also don't do inserts/deletes yet). Anyone want to modify it?

Comment: A summary of what I found so far: no combination of replacing `x` with `y`, `y` with `x`, or changing the digit in the `range` result in 19 tildes. I also experimented with inserting a `-` before either `x` or `y`, and with changing `%` to one of `+ - / *`, to no avail. I'm fairly certain now that 1 or 2 inserts is required.

Comment: I got it. It's a good one.

Comment: Okay, my first link now cracks it correctly.

Comment: Well done, the solution was indeed to change it to a set comprehension.

Comment: I added a small explanation, I actually think this one was really clever. I don't know that I've ever even seen a set comprehension, and also relying on Python leaking `y` into the enclosing scope was a nice touch.

Comment: Nice! I doubt I would have found that. I've never used a set comprehension before. The scope leaking was interesting as well.

Answer (score 6):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54707#54707)

## PHP, 164 bytes

### Code

```php
$S_U_M_M_E_R = 1;
$A_U_T_U_M_N = 2;
$T_I_M_E = 1;

if ($T_I_M_E == $S_U_M_M_E_R) {
    $A_C_=$T_I_=$O_N= 'SWIM' ? 'TAN' : 'DRINK';
}

print $T_I_M_E * $A_U_T_U_M_N;
```

### Original Output

```
2
```

### Changed output

```
-1.1306063769532
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54707)

Comment: Well done! I didn't think it would be that easy to be cracked.

Answer (score 5):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54763)

## [APL](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/), 7 bytes

## Code

```
-/3⍴157
```

## Original output

```
157
```

## Changed output

```
0.11479360684269167J0.37526348448410907
```

Comment: Is that `J` in the output evidence that it's a complex number?

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes, `aJb` refers to the complex number `a + bi`.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54763)

Answer (score 4):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54484/20080)

## C, 53 bytes

### Code

```
main(a,_){puts(_*_*_*_*_-1?"Expected Output":"?");}
```

### Original Output

```
Expected Output
```

### Changed output

```
?
```

Probably too easy, but who knows. (Note: it is technically system dependent but the type of system on which it fails would also fail all the other submissions here, so I figured it was a moot point).

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54493/20080)

## Edit

I made a mistake. New code which is more secure to the obvious attack:

```
main(a,_){puts(_*_-1||_*_*_-1||_*_*_*_-1?"Expected Output":"?");}
```

same outputs. New size of 65 bytes. Hopefully harder... though still probably too easy.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54484/29577)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54493/32700)

Comment: (side note - this should probably have been two answers)

Comment: @Sp3000 You may be right, although the goal of the original was to have the same solution, I just focussed too much on the problem of odd * count (where you can turn the middle one into a /) and didn't consider the easier *0 change.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 28 bytes (safe)

```
"jK=\~"5*)ib257b~{G$5$+}*]Jb
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22jK%3D%5C~%225*)ib257b~%7BG%245%24%2B%7D*%5DJb).

#### Original output

```
7705397905065379035618588652533563996660018265606606763127193120855297133322151462150247488267491212817218321670720380456985476811737021068519164822984561148339610474891720342171053455881107227302663880445203851079295537592154028123394687360216561235621729967011148112746984677807932995700334185726563970223018774
```

#### Modified output

```
16650180159137697345989048346412185774444335111603430666402604460993564226370500963166158223117360250140073061887053326627468495236957122711656527124216908303912850181595147494475577084810653496778801228980874902968634143062
```

#### Solution

```
"jK=\~"5*Wcib257b~{G$5$+}*]Jb
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22jK%3D%5C~%225*Wcib257b~%7BG%245%24%2B%7D*%5DJb)

#### How it works

I went a little overboard with this one...

The original code does the following:

```
"jK=\~"5* e# Push "jK=\~jK=\~jK=\~jK=\~jK=\~".
)i        e# Pop the last character and cast it to integer.
b257b     e# Convert the remainder of the string from that base to base 257.
~         e# Dump all resulting base-257 digits on the stack:
          e# 137 72 124 88 81 145 85 32 28 251 118 230 53 13 245 147 256 116 187 22 224
{         e# Do the following 224 times:
  G$5$+   e#   Add copies of the 5th and 17th topmost integers on the stack
          e#   (recurrence of a lagged Fibonacci sequence).
}*        e#
]         e# Wrap the entire stack in an array.
Jb        e# Convert from base 19 to integer.
          e# The resulting integer is printed implicitly.
```

The intended change is replacing `(i` with `Wci`.

This leaves the repeated string untouched and pushes **65535** (by casting to an unsigned 16-bit character, then back to integer), so that the first elements of the lagged Fibonacci sequence become

```
87 225 162 210 73 196 142 219 175 61 40 147 0 93 75 55 103 116 237 188 108 122 176 133 135 240 251 155 224 82 181 75 23 87 139 49 148 169 84 109 110 166 52 103 83 185 78 73
```

and the loop is repeated **126** times.

Comment: This is safe now, isn't it?

Comment: @BetaDecay I pretty much used the same trick in both CJam answers, so I had to wait to post both solutions at once. It is safe now.

Comment: Once I worked out what this was, I realised there was so many things that could be tweaked that I didn't even bother trying to brute force this one... nice work :)

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 47 (safe)

### Code

```
for(var i=64460,x=773;i>=1324;)x=i--/x;alert(x)
```

### Original Output

```
11.948938595656971
```

### Changed output

```
3.679331284911481
```

Distance is exactly 15.

Tested in Chrome and IE.

### Solution

```
for(var i=64460,x=773;i>>=1<324;)x=i--/x;alert(x)
```

This uses the bit shift assignment operator `i>>=1` to make the loop interval non-linear. Also this has the amusing property that someone trying to brute force a solution will run into several variations that run infinitely.

Answer (score 4):

[Cracked by issacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54664#54664)

## MATLAB, 20 bytes

### Code

```
format long
sin(i^pi)
```

### Original Output

```
0.331393418243797 - 1.109981778186163i
```

### Changed Output

```
0.220584040749698 - 0.975367972083631i
```

Comment: I tried a bunch of ideas in the Octave interpreter online. Still nothing. I tried things like using `sinh`, `asin`, `tan`, `pi^i`, etc...

Comment: @mbomb007 - I'm at a loss here too... and I'm 5th highest on StackOverflow in MATLAB overall!

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54664/20080)

Answer (score 4):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54754/43044)

## Octave, 20 bytes

```
format long;
cos(1)*1
```

### Output:

```
0.540302305868140
```

### Changed Output:

```
111
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54754)

Comment: Note: This is _only_: Octave, not "Octave / MATLAB", which is often the case.

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 100 bytes

### Code

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<[>.+<-]
```

### Original output

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

### Changed output

```
[
  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Note: Possibly easy to crack. But then, nothing is easy in Brainfuck.

Comment: Are there any unprintable characters in the output?

Comment: Seems like a few got eaten but there's still a lot of unprintables left when I try and copy and paste, so I'm assuming [this is it](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54480/21487)

Comment: @Sp3000 Er- no, there shouldn't be any unprintables. Which interpreter are  you using?

Comment: The method isn't equal to mine, either- keep trying.

Comment: When I try to copy and paste the changed output string into Python I get `'[\n\x0b\x0c  \x0e\x0f\x10\x13!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`, indicating some unprintables at the start of the string...

Comment: When I try to put it in Python it hides the \n\x0b...\x13 part and just gives me errors about the spacing. Let me try with alternative interpreters/charsets.

Comment: By copying and pasting I mean as an actual string, so surrounding the whole thing with triple quotes. A newline is definitely there, so you should definitely have `\n` at least...

Comment: I've just opened it with LiClipse and there is a newline, but it's way off where your result has it.

Comment: Are you trying your changed output above or the actual output from the interpreter? Remember that SE mangles unprintables

Comment: The actual interpreter. Still not working. I'll have to try it on a different laptop.

Comment: As an even more exciting development, if I paste the output string into bash the terminal stops as if I've typed `^S` and doesn't start until I type `^Q`.

Comment: If you can post the actual ASCII codes of the output that would be awesome.

Comment: I'd like to ping you again to reply to the comments above. At the moment we're in limbo with this being cracked or uncracked

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54497/20080)

## Java, 149 Characters

```java
class T{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(((Integer.MAX_VALUE^25214903917L)&281474976710655L)*25214903917L+11L&281474976710655L);}}
```

### Original Output

```java
174542852132661
```

### Modified Output

```java
106906909674100
```

Hint:

> Random.java

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54497/19349)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54510/20080)

## [Fantom](http://fantom.org/), 26

### Code

```
Float.makeBits(1123581321)
```

### Original Output

```
5.55122931E-315
```

### Changed output

```
124.24518585205078
```

Security Through Obscurity, if nobody knows the language, nobody can crack it. Levenshtein Distance of 15. Run it in fansh.

Comment: I guess I need to learn Fantom...

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54510/19349)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54638/34718)

## VBA, 72 bytes

```
Sub q()
Dim a(2) As Double
a(0)=-5
a(1)=10
msgbox IRR(a,0.253)
End Sub
```

**Original Output**

```
 0.999999999999136
```

**Adjusted Output**

```
1.82842712474619
```

Need to see some more VBA representation round here.=) Runs in Excel 2007+

Comment: The adjusted output looks so familiar. I feel like that's a number I ought to know.

Comment: @AlexVanLiew The adjusted output is probably equal to `2*sqrt(2)-1` according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.82842712474619)

Comment: @mbomb007 Yeah, that's what I was thinking too. I also feel like that number holds some significance, but I don't think it's a trig special angle and I can't think of what might generate it.

Comment: The original output ≈ `1157407407406 / 1157407407407`, but I don't think this is significant. I think it's more important to understand how `IRR()` works, which I don't.

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54638/34718)

Comment: Good job. Its hard to hide what your doing in vba. So i went with the fact there are a lot of obscure libraries for finance functions that i thought most programmers won't know what they do. Sadly programmers are fast learners. Might have to try again a little more obscure this time.

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54605/7951)

## SWI-Prolog, 54 bytes

### Code

```
assert(d(E,F):-(print(E),print(F))). d(123456,123456).
```

### Original Output

```
true.

123456123456
true.
```

### Changed output

```
true.

false.
```

Comment: I tried to get a SWI-Prolog interpreter working the other day but couldn't, so I'll take a stab in the dark; if you remove the `E` and `F` in the `print` statements do you get what you want?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew I'm getting syntax errors from that

Comment: @AlexVanLiew Incorrect

Comment: Ah well. Worth a shot.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54605/7951)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54521/20080)

### CJam, 6 characters

```
25mse7
```

**Original output**

```
-1323517.5009777304
```

**Changed output**

```
72004899337.38588
```

This might be too easy. :P

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54521) The output is slightly different in my browser (and entirely different with the Java interpreter).

Comment: @Dennis Not entirely sure why, but the changes are correct.

Answer (score 3):

[Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54753/6828)

## Ruby, 24

### Code

```
p _=?9;p$.+=1until 9#$./
```

### Original Output

```
"9"
```

### Changed output

```
"9"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Do all Ruby programs look like someone took a shotgun loaded with ASCII and shot it at the screen, or just the ones that I see here?

Comment: Ruby was designed to let you choose whether you imitated Perl (seemingly any random keysmash is valid syntax) or Python (just copy-paste the pseudocode and you're good to go). On these sorts of challenges Perlisms tend to do better.

Comment: No kidding. I couldn't even figure out what the original snippet does (random space between `p` and `_`? adding 1 to the value of the global that keeps track of line numbers 9 times? or adding 1 to the value of `p$.`, which ought to be `nil`, which seems like it ought to throw an error?). I'll leave this one for one of the greats. Or at least someone that knows Ruby, ahaha.

Comment: The  `"9"` and trailing `/` makes me think there is a regex involved here

Comment: This one is totally messing with me... Closest so far is `p _=?9;p$.+=1until 9<$.`... Arrgghh! :)

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54753)

Comment: Argh, well done, almost made it to 3 days.

Comment: Sorry, pipped at the post! I will admit that I spent a long time obsessing over comparisons before your mention of Perlisms and @gnibbler's comment about regex got me there in the end! Enjoyed that though, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [cracked](/a/54601)

## modern Perl 5, 70

### Code

```
@array = (qw smiles) x 11;
s/.*// foreach @array;
print "@array\n";
```

### Original Output

A single newline.

### Changed output

```
 mile mile mile mile mile mile mile mile mile mile
```

The output begins with a space and ends with a newline.

Comment: @AlexVanLiew *Note that there's a space before the first m!*

Comment: @Dennis Oh no! I knew it couldn't be that simple.

Comment: I'm not sure, but [I think I have it](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54601/21487)...

Comment: @DomHastings Yep! Well solved. As someone commented on your solution, the additional character can be an extra space anywhere. I said "modern" Perl 5 because `each` applies to an array only since some version.

Comment: If he hadn't cracked it, would you have said "missed it by a mile"? :D

Comment: @mbomb007 I kept thinking of that joke when I was trying to find a way to get that 11th `mile` out of the output.

Comment: @mbomb007 I suffered that too, needed to change a third character to solve it that way.

Answer (score 3):

### [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54655/34718)

### bc, 22 bytes

```
4518574615489737231532
```

Current output

```
4518574615489737231532
```

Desired output

```
195543687803724
```

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54655/34718)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54616/31516)

## Matlab, 12 bytes

### Code

```
-sin(2:.5:3)
```

### Original output

```
-0.9093   -0.5985   -0.1411
```

### Changed output

```
0.4228    0.7032    0.9228
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54616/31516)!

Comment: @StewieGriffin Hey, well done!

Answer (score 3):

### [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54686#54686)

### Lua, 55 bytes

Now with less skimpy underwear!
This code might look like my last code that was sadly cracked, but I can assure the solution is completely different

```
G={load="lfkjgGsHjkU83fy6dtrg"}
print(tostring(G.load))
```

Current output:

```
lfkjgGsHjkU83fy6dtrg
```

The correct output on 64 bit machines:

```
26
```

And on 32 bit machines:

```
18
```

Comment: I can't quite figure this one out.

Comment: Sorry, the output is that number. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: [Cracked by Xrott?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54686)

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's the intended solution

Answer (score 3):

### perl, 12 bytes

## [cracked](/a/54613/20198)

Code

```
print sin 97
```

Original output

```
0.379607739027522
```

Desired output

```
-0.64618863474386
```

Comment: I can confirm it's almost certainly not `print sin xx`, `print sin xx97`, or `print sin 97xx` where `xx` is any two numbers.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54613/20198)

Comment: @DomHastings indeed - well done. Out of interest how did you do that?

Comment: After reading @AlexVanLiew's comment, I tested similar numbers `9.?7`, `9.7?`, etc, but realised it had to be an operator. Tried all I could think of in snippets like `perl -e 'print map{sin((+"9${_}")x7).$/}1..9'` eventually got the right combination!

Comment: @DomHastings belated +1 for your crack then.

Answer (score 3):

### [Cracked by Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54640/18)

## MATLAB, 62 bytes

### Code

```
mistake=-1;tragic=rosser;a=hilb(8)*42;
a(:,:)+tragic(8)/mistake
```

### Original Output

```
   13.0000   -8.0000  -15.0000  -18.5000  -20.6000  -22.0000  -23.0000  -23.7500
   -8.0000  -15.0000  -18.5000  -20.6000  -22.0000  -23.0000  -23.7500  -24.3333
  -15.0000  -18.5000  -20.6000  -22.0000  -23.0000  -23.7500  -24.3333  -24.8000
  -18.5000  -20.6000  -22.0000  -23.0000  -23.7500  -24.3333  -24.8000  -25.1818
  -20.6000  -22.0000  -23.0000  -23.7500  -24.3333  -24.8000  -25.1818  -25.5000
  -22.0000  -23.0000  -23.7500  -24.3333  -24.8000  -25.1818  -25.5000  -25.7692
  -23.0000  -23.7500  -24.3333  -24.8000  -25.1818  -25.5000  -25.7692  -26.0000
  -23.7500  -24.3333  -24.8000  -25.1818  -25.5000  -25.7692  -26.0000  -26.2000
```

### Changed Output

```
  -22.0000   19.0000   11.0000  -50.5000  -51.6000    1.0000   -1.0000  -51.7500
   12.0000  -41.0000  -43.5000   -3.6000   -6.0000  -45.0000  -44.7500  -11.3333
   -3.0000  -36.5000  -37.6000  -13.0000  -15.0000  -37.7500  -37.3333  -19.8000
  -29.5000  -17.6000  -20.0000  -31.0000  -30.7500  -25.3333  -26.8000  -29.1818
  -23.6000  -27.0000  -29.0000  -23.7500  -23.3333  -33.8000  -35.1818  -21.5000
  -34.0000  -17.0000  -16.7500  -39.3333  -40.8000  -15.1818  -14.5000  -44.7692
  -43.0000   -9.7500   -9.3333  -47.8000  -49.1818   -7.5000   -6.7692  -53.0000
   -2.7500  -53.3333  -54.8000   -1.1818   -0.5000  -58.7692  -60.0000    1.8000
```

Comment: That's just evil. lol.

Comment: @rayryeng: but it has 42 in it!

Comment: ... and that's why it's even more evil lol.  We still don't know what the question is!

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54640/36398)

Answer (score 3):

### [Cracked by Luiz Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54634/18)

### MATLAB, 40 bytes

## Code

```
format long
arg = [.1 .2 .3];
sin(arg'*exp(9))
```

### Original Output

```
  -0.220680258232564
  -0.430479305680324
  -0.619052457794081
```

### Changed Output

```
  -0.803636351328917
  -0.721159584869623
  -0.148487879352133
```

Hint: there's another solution to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54620/18)

Comment: But this doesn't fulfill the minimum Levenshtein distance requirement

Comment: The Lev. distance for this code is 12.  Minimum is 15.

Comment: @rayryeng: apologies, `format long` added :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54634/36398)

Comment: @LuisMendo: good job!

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54681#54681)

## Javascript, 53 bytes

### Code

```
a=(((b=(a=1)+a)+a)-b-a)*(a=[b])['length'];
alert(a);
```

### Original Output

```
0
```

### Changed output

```
5.551115123125783e-18
```

Tested under: Firefox, Chrome, IE

Comment: Interesting. So far, I managed to find `5.551115123125783e-17`.

Comment: I confirm that it should be e-18. I noticed myself the solution for e-17

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54681/25180)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54710/19349).

## [Stuck](https://github.com/kade-robertson/stuck), 21 Bytes

I'll start with an easy one, since nobody has seen this before and there's no documents.. Anyways, Stuck is a stack-based language, very similar in usage to CJam. All you need to know is:

```
NR -> creates a range [1,N] on the stack. 
[N]z -> zips together the top 2 lists, unless an optional N is specified, then the top N lists.
] -> Flattens the top list by one "dimension".
```

For the record, while I have made commits since this challenge happened, all of this functionality has been present long before.

#### Code:

```
1R2R3R4R5R6R7R8R9R9z]
```

#### Original Output:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

#### Changed Output:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: I made a minor edit that I think helps clarify the commands, let me know if it looks good.

Comment: @AlexVanLiew Yeah, that should help clarify :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem. One other thing: does the `R` command create an inclusive range or an exclusive range? ie, does `1R` push an empty list, or does it push `[1]`? (same thing for `2R`, does it push `[1]` or `[1, 2]`?)

Comment: @AlexVanLiew Just clarified that in the post. It's inclusive.

Comment: Looks good now!

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54710/19349)

Answer (score 3):

## [Fantom](http://fantom.org/), 30 (safe)

### Code

```
[7115432d/9,219.or(64),37][0]
```

### Original Output

```
790603.5555555556
```

### Changed output

```
55
```

### Solution

```
"7115432d/9,219.or(64),37"[0]
```

By changing the array to a string literal, the index call actually gets the first character of the string. Characters in fantom are actually just ints, so the value of '7' is 55.

Comment: Hey, you can still change the `.` to a `,` and change the index to `3` (`[7115432d/9,219.or(64),37,55,0f][3]`). I'll give you grace so you can fix it up again. ;P

Comment: Hey, thanks, that distraction was too much work for what it was worth

Comment: You enjoy red herrings, don't you? `119.xor(64)` is so close!

Comment: @AlexVanLiew Haha that's the idea, I wanted 55 to come up all over the place

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell v3, 384 (SAFE)

(My second post ever on PPCG, please be gentle. :) I think I'm going to like this community!)

### Code:

```
$s="a*h*t*s*m*i*d*o*n*l*k*e*y*u*g*r*w*LOOD> AIG BAE>!+<R S!>>+<GH MHN JFKL> LOOD AIG BAE>?<+"
$cur="";$l="";[char]$n="A";$st=@{}
foreach($c in [char[]]$s){switch -regex($c){
"[\*\>]" {$st[$n]=$cur.TrimStart(" ");$n=[char]([int]$n-1);if($c-eq">"){$l+=$cur};$cur=""}
"\+" {$l=$cur;$cur=""}
"\<" {$l+$cur;$l="";$cur=""}
default {if($st.Contains($c)){$cur+=$st[$c]}else{$cur+=$c}}}}
```

### Original output:

```
eggs and ham!
eggs and ham!
do you like eggs and ham?
```

### Modified output:

```
!

GH MHN JFKL LOOD aIG BaEt
```

(to be clear, that's a blank line in the middle of the modified output)

Mini-hint:

> h/t to Adam Barr for the inspiration

### Edit - Safe - Below is corrected code, and below that is explanation

```
$s = "a*h*t*s*m*i*d*o*n*l*k*e*y*u*g*r*w*LOOD> AIG BAE>!+<R S!>>+<GH MHN JFKL> LOOD AIG BAE>?<+" # The string we're cycling through
$cur = "" # What word(s) we've currently built
$l = "" # The current line we've finished building
[char]$n = "A" # Cast as a character instead of a string, this is the index of our temporary store
$st = @{} # Our temporary store - the first time through, this will populate out with the first part of the string $s
foreach ($c in [char[]]$s) { # Loop through the string $s as an array, one $c character at a time
    switch -regex ($c) {
        "[\*\>]" {
            $st[$n] = $cur.TrimStart(" ") # Ensures that we're not adding a space, and adds what we've currently built into the store
            $n = [char]([int]$n + 1)    #ONE OF THE CHANGES - Changed the +1 to -1, which causes the indexing of the store to be off
            if ($c -eq ">") { $l += $cur } # If our current character is a >, add that to the line as it's finished
            $cur = "" # Reset what we're building
        }
        "\+" {
            $l += $cur #ONE OF THE CHANGES - Changed the += to =, which causes the line to not get printed
            $cur = "" # Reset what we're building
        }
        "\<" {
            $l + $cur # Add on our current word to the line and print it out
            $l = "" # Reset our line
            $cur = "" # Reset what we're building
        }
        default {
            if ($st.Contains($c)) {
                $cur += $st[$c] # If our store contains the character, add what's in the store's index at $c to our current word
            } else {
                $cur += $c # Else, just add the character to our current word
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Explanation

The best way to explain this is that we're using the string at the start as a sort of cypher. The first half of the string, demarcated by asterisks, is our cypher results. The rest of the string is the output, encoded based off of the "integer" value of the letter (from an alphabetical perspective, not an ASCII perspective). For example, the `LOOD>` takes the 12th character (an `e`), the 15th character (a `g`) twice, and then the 4th character (a `s`), which forms the word `eggs`, then the `>` case, which trims off what we're building so that our words don't run together.

The script cycles through the string character by character, building the cypher store at first (because of all the asterisks, the first 34 times through the switch causes either the first case or the default case to be called), while the rest of the times through cause either an index lookup (because we've already added that letter) or text manipulation (e.g., the second change which just re-sets a variable rather than print it out).

Please let me know if you have further questions!

Comment: This is safe now, you can reveal the solution if you wish

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge 98, 30 Bytes(Safe)

### Code

```
153+:*,+:f`#v_
+ ':_;#:-1;#@;,
```

### Original output:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

### Changed output:

```
@~}|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"!
```

### Solution

```
g53+:*,+:f`#v_
+ ':_;#:-1;#<@;,
```

Comment: Why u so cruel?!

Comment: Is there a trailing space in the changed output?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew no trailing space. The '!' is the last character.

Comment: Alright, I might give this a try when I get home. I've always wanted an excuse to learn this language. Can you link to the interpreter/compiler you used?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew http://befungius.aurlien.net

Comment: @MegaTom I can tell you worked hard on this. I can sort of see what I need to do but I don't know how to do it with just two changes, especially since the second line doesn't contain any flow control.

Comment: This is safe now, you can reveal the solution of you wish

Comment: @MegaTom Nice! I was getting pretty close; I had a pretty good idea of what the last line looked like and I looked into using `g`, but I didn't try it right there.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 49 byes (safe)

### Code

```
$_=cos 99;printf"%.16f",0x7275*sin $_/s/[3-8]/04/
```

### Original Output

```
145.9795577401910975
```

### Changed Output

```
23.3077670014990304
```

---

### Clue

I tried to do this before but there was another unintended (easier) solution.  The [robber](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54737#54737) to my previous challenge may help you solve this one.  Try to solve it with *three* modifications and you'll be half way to the two modification answer.

## Solution

> ```
> $_=cos 99;printf"%.16f",07275*sin $_/y/[3-8]/04/
> ```
>
> 1. Remove the `x` to turn hexadecimal `0x7275` (decimal 29301) into octal `07275` (decimal 3773)
>
> 2. Change the `s///` (replacement) to `y///` (transliteration) so that instead of *the first* digit from 3-8 becoming the string `04`, *all* digits in that range become `4`. Additionally, both return the number of changes; the `s///` version only makes one change while `y///` makes all 8 changes (the way `s///g` would). If you could change a *third* character, you could do `s/[3-8]/4/g` and have the same result as my `y/[3-8]/04/`. (This was exploited to solve my [previous attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54735/43035).)
>
> Example of `s///` vs `y///`:
>
> ```
> $_="s: 1234567890, ";s/[3-8]/04/;print; $_="y: 1234567890";y/[3-8]/04/;print
> ```
>
> ```
> s: 12044567890, y: 1244444490
> ```
>
> So therefore we're multiplying by a changed number and the function at the end alters the default variable differently and divides by a different number.

Comment: Good going! Closest I got was `23.5402686025187862` with `$_=cos 99;printf"%.16f",0x1275*sin $_/s/[3-8]/04/` didn't think to change the `s///`, d'oh!

Answer (score 3):

## Malbolge, 411 bytes

#### Code

```
bCBA@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"!~}|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9y76543210/(L,l$H('&%$#"!~}v{zyxwvutm3qponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]?zZYXWVOTSRQPONMFjJIHGFEDC<`@?!=<;4X87w/S3s10/.-,+*)('&%$#"!~}|{zyxq7Xtmrk1onPlkdihg`&dcbD`_^]\[ZYXQutTSRQPONMLKJCgGFEDCBA@?>=<;:z81Uv43210/.'Kl*#G'&f|{A!~}|{zs9qvo5mrqponmle+*hgfe^c\"`_^]\[ZYXWV8Nr5QPONGkKJ,HGFEDCBA@?>=<;:3W76/432+O/o-,+*)('&%|B/
```

#### Original output

```
Two Makes All The Difference
```

#### Modified output

```
Two
```

(note the trailing space)

#### Solution

```
bCBA@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"!~}|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9y76543210/(L,l$H('&%$#"!~}v{zyxwvutm3qponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]?zZYXWcOTSRQPONMFjJIHGFEDC<`@?!=<;4X87w/S3s10/.-,+*)('&%$#"!~}|{zyxq7Xtmrk1onPlkdihg`&dcbD`_^]\[ZYXQutTSRQPONMLKJCgGFEDCBA@?>=<;:z81Uv43210/.'Kl*#G'&f|{A!~}|{zs9qvo5mrqponmle+*hgfe^c\"`_^]\[ZYXWV8sr5QPONGkKJ,HGFEDCBA@?>=<;:3W76/432+O/o-,+*)('&%|B/
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54518/20080)

**C++ 91 Bytes**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    //can you figure it out?
    std::cout << "I like cake and";
}
```

**Output:**

> I like cake and

**Changed output**

> 

Comment: Your *changed output* is unclear? Is empty, a single newline or something else?

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54518/19349) I'm not really sure this is valid, though, as the spec says that output must be non-empty; it's unclear if this refers to both outputs or just the original one.

Comment: This is invalid. *None* of the outputs can be empty. CC @AlexVanLiew

Comment: Alex, I can't comment on the other post (not enough rep) but you got me

Comment: @f41lurizer Good try for a first post, but trigraphs and other similar shenanigans are pretty well known around here. Try giving it another go!

Comment: Trigraphs are [forbidden in underhanded](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1283/34718), and this is kinda of like an underhanded.

Comment: I mean, you could also just add `//` before `std::cout`...

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54543/21487)

## Python 2, 57 bytes

### Code

```
i=long;j=map;print reduce(i.__mul__,j(i,j(ord,`i`)))/1234
```

### Original Output

```
3164217824783520557889
```

### Changed output

```
9072146982802639849575831250318562874251
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54543/21487)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2/3, 70 bytes (safe)

### Code

```
x=932436
for i in range(99**4):x=(1103515245*x+12345)%2**31
print(x*x)
```

### Original Output

```
211455574532454121
```

### Changed output

```
1039038861760158249
```

### Solution

```
x=9372436
for i in range(59**4):x=(1103515245*x+12345)%2**31
print(x*x)
```

The solution initializes `x` to `9372436` instead of `932436`, and does `range(59**4)` instead of `range(99**4)`. As an aside, the solution runs in about 1/10th of the time.

I probably could have made it shorter without making it too much easier, or at all easier.

Comment: This is python 3 only, but i assume that using python 2 won't hurt (original code returns `(459842989, 459842989)`)

Comment: Oh yea, I doubled the output to conform to the Levenshtein distance rule; forgot it would be a tuple in Python 2. Still, same effect.

Comment: Since you use brackets on the print, I think you should say this is Python 3, for good form

Comment: Those two parentheses are the only difference between Python 2 only and Python 2/3; the output is slightly different in each, but I don't think that violates any rules; certainly not the spirit of the rules. But if it really is bad form, I guess I'd go with the Python 2 only version to save 1 byte.

Comment: wouldn't `print(x*x)` work ok too?

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks @gnibbler :).

Comment: @Cyphase *The output slightly differs*... In that case you have to choose one or the other

Comment: @BetaDecay, not anymore, thanks to gnibbler's comment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54554/21487)

## Python 2, 41 bytes

### Code

```
print sum((ord(i)<<0x156 for i in `sum`))
```

### Original Output

```
19718712710133388269747721838124583424582966957653854505259504044885223633870136963133245450763229047291904
```

### Changed output

```
20
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54554/21487)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54553/20198)

## PHP 5.4, 92 bytes

```php
<?php
define('E','!');

$x = 4;
$t = " Hello World";
$t .= E;
$t .= E;
$t .= E;

print($t);
```

#### Output:

```
 Hello World!!!
```

#### Changed Output:

```
 Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!
```

(Note: both outputs include a leading space)

Comment: Please refer to the formatting guide (Byte count is missing) ;)

Comment: @BetaDecay sorry, I missed that! Usually I omit that from non-golfed code and completely missed it in the rules!

Comment: It's fine by me :-D

Comment: [Crack attempt #2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54553/20198)

Comment: @NathanMerrill You got it!

Answer (score 2):

### [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54573/42619)

### Lua, 54 Bytes

```
G={string="gs_hSDrGSFG5;U*ts"}
print(tostring(G.string))
```

Current output:

```
gs_hSDrGSFG5;U*ts
```

Desired output:

```
23
```

Note: I'm  not exactly sure why, but if you are using an online compiler (specifically repl.it) the correct output will be 15.

Comment: Could you post which environment you're using that achieves 23? I can get 15 in lots of different ways on repl.it and lua53.exe.

Comment: Lua 5.2 on Windows 7. Don't think it makes a difference, but installed through LuaRocks.

Comment: This might give it away, but the way you tell is this program:
t = {}
print(t)
If it says
table: 0000000(random numbers) then the correct answer is 23, if it says 0x(random stuff) the correct answer is 15.

Comment: Hmm. Well, [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54573/19349)? I'm almost certain the reason the 15/23 difference exists is because the intended solution has to do with pointer size (if you print a table, it prints the memory location); so on a 64-bit system you go from a 8-character pointer to a 16-character pointer; which accounts for the missing (extra?) 8 characters. I'll see if I can figure out what the intended solution was in the meantime, though.

Comment: Actually no, I'm going to edit my code a bit. The only reason you got 15 is because the length of G.string is 15, but the length of G is only 15 because of the Levenshtien distance rule. Sorry about that, I'm going to edit my code.

Comment: Bahaha. Don't forget to edit the output too! ;P @BetaDecay, what do you think about this?

Comment: I mean, you technically didn't get it because you were getting 15 on something you should have been getting 23 on, but then again... This is weird. We will differ to the judgement of the OP. Sorry about this.

Comment: I understand how the intended solution is supposed to look, but I don't know enough Lua syntax to figure out how to do it, ahaha. Until OP responds I'll keep looking for the intended solution.

Comment: I fixed it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54568#54568)

## Javascript, 169 bytes

### Code

```js
a=1,b=a*2,c=a+b,d=[a+b];while(c>b)c-=a;for(i=1;i<=c;i++)d.push(i);i=''+c*d['length']*d['length'];alert(Math[String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt(0) * i.charCodeAt(1) / 32)])
```

### Original Output

```
undefined
```

### Changed output

```
2.718281828459045
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54568)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54577#54577)

## MATLAB / OCTAVE, 28 bytes

## Code:

```
f=@(x)x^.7;g=@(x)7/f(x);g(7)
```

## Original output:

```
ans =

    1.7928
```

## Changed output

```
ans =

  -0.3011 - 0.4144i
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54577#54577)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54572/19349)

## Clojure, 35 Bytes

### Code

```
(printf "%d\n" 2155263413256326162)
```

### Original Output

```
2155263413256326162
nil
```

### Changed output

```
3681347803529195
nil
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54572/19349)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54594/36398)

## MATLAB / Octave, 33 bytes

### Code

```
eig(cov(reshape(sin(1:60),5,[])))
```

### Original Output

```
ans =

   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    2.4410
    4.5766
```

### Changed Output

```
ans =

    0.0064
    0.0000
    0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
    0.0000
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54594/36398)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54588/14732)

## PHP, 21 bytes

### Code

```
print_r(range(i,09));
```

### Original Output

> `Array ( [0] => 0 )`

### Changed output

> `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 )`

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54588/19349)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fantom](http://fantom.org/), 34

### Code

```
[7115432d/9,219.or(64),37,5555][0]
```

### Original Output

```
790603.5555555556
```

### Changed output

```
55
```

Ok, hopefully this one is a little more competitive than my previous attempt. Levenshtein Distance of 15. Run it in fansh.

### Better Code

@isaacg found an easy solution I hadn't even seen. This code removes that solution while keeping the original one I intended, if anyone still wants the challenge.

```
[7115432d/9,219.or(64),37,55.0f][0]
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54599/20080)

Comment: This is clearly not my game

Comment: @Sp3000 I mean the new code I posted is the one to be cracked, without the loophole I missed that isaacg found.

Comment: I think it'd be better to make a new answer for that (or you won't show up on the snippet)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54611/42978)

## Matlab/Octave, 10 bytes

this should be a fairly easy one.

I only tried it with [Octave online](http://octave-online.net/), but it should run fine in matlab.

### Code:

```
e^(i*pi)+1
```

### Output

```
0.0000e+00 + 1.2246e-16i
```

### Changed Output

```
1.9336e+04
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54611/20080)

Comment: @isaacg not the solution i had intended, but it works ;)
to keep it short i left out the `format long`, then using `2` would not match the output.

but nevertheless, well done!

Comment: `+e` then, I assume?

Comment: @isaacg right ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes (safe)

### Code

```
z=Zeta[4/3,1/2];N[Min[z,Sec[z]],20]
```

### Original Output

```
1.4508303658284314991
```

### Changed output

```
-0.72451364607415832407
```

Edit: Note that the original code will sort-of work on Wolfram Alpha, but the modified code does not.

## Changed Code

```
z=Zeta[4/3,1/2];N[Sin[z,Set[z]],20]
```

`Set[z]` evaluates to `Sequence[]` so `Sin[z,Set[z]] = Sin[z]`. Moreover, Mathematica evaluates function arguments serially and in order, so `Set[z]` is evaluated after the value of `z` is already used.

Comment: I hate seeing answers in Mathematica, since it's a proprietary language. There's no way for us to test it if we don't pay for it.

Comment: @mbomb007 Many people on PPCG do have a copy of Mathematica. If you don't, then you can simply scroll past my answer.

Comment: Sometimes they work on WolframAlpha.

Comment: @mbomb007 - MATLAB is as well, but I don't see people complaining about it.  Octave is not a full replacement to MATLAB, much like Wolfram Alpha isn't a replacement for Mathematica.  I like seeing Mathematica code because it's cool to see how some minor changes gives you extraordinarily different output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54680)

## GolfScript, 4 bytes

```
9,!9
```

#### Original output

```
09
```

(trailing linefeed)

#### Modified output

```
0123456789012345678
```

(no trailing linefeeed)

---

If you test your code in [Web GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com), you have to look at the source code of the output, since the (lack of a) trailing linefeed will be undetectable in the rendered page. For the correct solution, there should be no linefeed between `0123456789012345678` and `</textarea>`.

It might be easier to use the [Ruby interpreter](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/) for this one.

Comment: 012345678*9*012345678?

Comment: Yes, the *9* has to stay.

Comment: [Muahaha][http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54672#54672]

Comment: Crap, how do I format that?

Comment: @BassetHound [text](link)

Comment: This is devilish ;)

Comment: How do I run the ruby interpreter?

Comment: @BassetHound `ruby golfscript.rb filename.gs` Requires Ruby. :P

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54680/25180)

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 56 bytes (SAFE)

I think this is a step up from some of the previous MATLAB questions, but that remains to be seen I guess:

## Code

```
p=.4 -.2*i;j=.3*i +.7;i=@(c)j./(.6- .4*c);asin(i(p) *5i)
```

## Original output

```
ans =

  -0.2236 + 2.8380i
```

## Changed output

```
ans =

   0.1799 + 6.5793i   0.1798 + 5.4395i
```

## Solution:

```
p=.4 -.2*i;j=.3*'i '+.7;i=@(c)j./(.6- .4*c);asin(i(p) *5i)
```

Simply change `.3*i +.7` to `.3*'i '+.7;` This creates a vector with the numbers `[105 32]`, since MATLAB automatically casts the chars to integers if it's part of an equation.

All the spaces were just to throw people off (it made it possible to do changes like `[.3*i 0.7];`, thus making it possible to create vectors this way too.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54704/34718)

## CSS, 53

### Code

```
body:after{counter-reset:a 512;content:counter(a)"₽"}
```

### Original Output

```
512₽
```

### Changed output

```
0%
```

### Snippet

```css
body:after{counter-reset:a 512;content:counter(a)"₽"}
```

Comment: "The changed output must have a Levenshtein Distance of 15 or more from your original output."

Comment: @Jakube, ok, I'll think about a fix. Anyway, there is no common symbols in input and output and it's impossible to only change output directly without getting my idea.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/54704/edit) and unfortunately i don't think a high enough distance is possible because `counter-reset` maxes at 2417483647

Comment: I was wrong, it is possible if you add multiple counters like so `body:after{counter-reset:a 2417483647;content:counter(a)counter(a)"₽"}`

Comment: @SLuck49 Your "cracked" link is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54795)

## APL, 5 characters

```
3⍟877
```

### Current output

```
6.1682424839682115
```

### Modified output

```
0.20016493054644696
```

An edit distance of 16.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54795)

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 9 bytes

### Code

```
+/○3-3⍴⍳5
```

### Original output

```
18.84955592153876
```

### Changed output

```
¯0.31830988618379086 0.31830988618379075 0
```

Looks like I just missed the deadline, because I suck at time zones. Have fun solving this, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54612/6638)

## SWI-Prolog, 54 bytes

### Code

```
assert((o(X,Y,Z):-ABC is X**X,print(ABC))). o(99,y,z).
```

### Original Output

```
true.

369729637649726772657187905628805440595668764281741102430259972423552570455277523421410650010128232727940978889548326540119429996769494359451621570193644014418071060667659301384999779999159200499899
true.
```

### Changed output

```
true.

true.
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54612/6638)

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ I'm not really sure if adding a whitespace counts as a "change", [I asked the OP about that](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/two-makes-all-the-difference-cops/54607?noredirect=1#comment132142_54464). If that's ok, then I'll accept it (the way I originally thought really requires two "effective" modifications).

Comment: Technically, I can also change the number `99`. It's also a trivial change anyway.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ In that case, well done! What I originally thought was replacing `o(99,y,z)` for `op(99,fy,z)`, so the 2nd call would just succeed without calling `o` (and without creating a choice point, like your solution).

Comment: BTW for everyone's reference, I only realized [a bit too late](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54612#comment131993_54605) how similar my attempt and [Fatalize's](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54516/7951) are (otherwise, I wouldn't even have posted this).

Answer (score 1):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54624#54624)

## Javascript, 233 bytes

### Code

```
one = 1;
two = one + one;
three = two + one;
zero = three - two - one;
numbers = [three, two, one];

for (i = numbers.length - 1; i >= zero; i--) {
    numbers.pop();
}

infinity = 1 / numbers['length'];
alert(infinity);
```

### Original Output

```
Infinity
```

### Changed output

```
3.333333333333333
```

Comment: I tested it on Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome. Windows 64bit. I guess your solution could be fine (maybe it's just a rounding in the end).

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54624/32628), Sorry @Sp3000, posted literal one second after your comment

Answer (score 1):

#### [Cracked, because I didn't check the simple solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54621/18)

## MATLAB, 8 bytes

### Code

```
sin(1+1)
```

### Original Output

```
0.909297426825682
```

### Changed Output

```
-0.262374853703929
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54621/21487) possibly?

Comment: you need `format long` enabled to see all the numbers

Comment: @Sp3000: yes, of course that works as well :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54697/20080)

## Python, 227 Bytes

## Original Code:

```
import re;''.join(re.findall('\w(?=\w\w)','t74q joh7 jv f9dfij9j bfjtf0e nnjen3j nnjrb6fgam3gtm5tem3hj s3eim7djsd3ye d5dfhg5un7ljmm8nan3nn6n k m2ftm5bsof5bf r5arm4ken8 adcm3nub0 nfrn6sn3jfeb6n d m6jda5 gdif5vh6 gij7fnb2eb0g '))
```

## Original Output:

```
't7jof9dfijbfjtfnnjennnjrb6fgam3gtm5tem3s3eim7djsd3d5dfhg5un7ljmm8nan3nnm2ftm5bsof5r5arm4keadcm3nunfrn6sn3jfebm6jdgdif5vgij7fnb2eb'
```

## Changed Output:

```
'to iterate is human to recurse divine'
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54697/20080)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 299

(I hope I have understood  the challenge correctly.  It seems hard to produce code where and 2 single-character changes make such a difference, even if ignoring whitespace etc.)

### Code

```
<?php $i=0x61;$x=0x15;$y=0x36;$k="";$me=<<<PHP
\$q=\$i=\$i-1;\$x++;\$x=\$x^\$i^$x;if(\$i>0){
for(\$z=0;\$z<__LINE__;\$z++){for(\$l=strlen
("\$me")-1;\$l>=0;\$l--)\$q=\$q^(int)(\$x^
ord(\$me[\$l]));}\$k.=\$q;\$me="/**/\$me";
\$me.="#";eval(\$me);}
PHP;
eval($me);echo wordwrap($k,30,"\n",true)."\n";
```

FYI: Proof it takes < 1 minute on any modern hardware:

```
$ time php /tmp/wot.php
711752729711068167264259526921
...
real    0m4.580s
user    0m1.548s
sys     0m3.023s
```

### Original Output

```
969594939291908988878685848382
818079787776757473727170696867
666564636261605958575655545352
515049484746454443424140393837
363534333231302928272625242322
212019181716151413121110987654
321
```

### Changed output

```
127127127127127255255255255255
255255255383383383383383383383
383383383511511511511511511511
511511511511511511511639639767
767767767767767895895895895895
895895895895102310231023102311
511151115111511151115111511151
115111511151127912791279127912
791279127912791407140714071407
140714071407140714071407153515
351535153515351535153515351535
```

Comment: I can see a huge number of possible permutations that could be tried in the hex values alone. This seems non-deterministic, which is to say, any small change you make, causes a huge pseudorandom output, so the only way to find it would be to brute force those numbers, or find a solution elsewhere in the code somehow.

Beyond my abiliity, I think.

Comment: Obviously my "solution" is (and always was) too long to be a winner ... so I'll drop some hints ;-)

The use of eval() is recursive - and changes the output if you add whitespace or debug code in it.  You could call the eval'd code directly - and just keep a copy of the eval'd variable string separately for it to use...

I think I'd advise you start there.

Comment: ...oh and it intentionally uses loops in loops to make it prohibitively "expensive" to brute force.  You might be able to optimize one of them out if you're careful.

Answer (score 1):

## OCTAVE, 157 bytes.

```
format long 
sin(cos(tan(csc(sec(cot(asin(acos(atan(acsc(asec(acot(sinh(cosh(tanh(csch(sech(coth(asinh(acosh(atanh(acsch(asech(acoth(i))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Output:`8.77828266022653e+276+3.46629794728664e+276i`

Modified Output:`1.32478170985912-7.32035312239031i`

Comment: Well that's just not fair ;)

Comment: @BetaDecay Of course it is. It abides by all the rules, eh? But brute force should be able to find the solution easily.

Comment: @VladimirLenin He made a winky-face. He knows it's fair. You must've missed it.

Comment: I give a simple estimate of a few thousand adjustments worth trying (roughly 3 for each trig function, choose 2).

Comment: @mbomb007 Then it should only take around $\binom{24}{2}\cdot 3^2=2484$ operations, much less than a second to run.

Comment: @mbomb007 Oops, accidentally put a acos instead of a acot in my code. Fixed

Comment: Is that one of the character changes? :) Or is it an intentional mind game to make us think it is. :S

Comment: @mbomb007 It is not, just an accidental copying error

Comment: I don't get that (original) output. I get `1.823149956544422e+206 -3.066417174909405e+206i`

Comment: @LuisMendo Are you using wolfram/Mathematica? Mathematica uses a different range of the acot() function. The answer displays correctly on the online interpreter for OCTAVE. The modified output on the other language should be the same, except that it is a plus instead of a minus in the middle.

Comment: I get `ans =  8.77828266017083e+276 + 3.46629794726118e+276i` using octave, which slightly differs from the output in the question.

Comment: @VladimirLenin I'm using Matlab R2014b

Comment: I get the wrong output too! It's hard to check if the solution is correct when the original output is different than what we get when running the code...Matlab R2011a and R2014b.

Comment: @Daniel probably some rounding errors or floating point errors

Comment: @LuisMendo it seems to be only compatible with octave, let me change the header

Comment: @VladimirLenin, have you checked if the result of the changed code is the same in MATLAB and Octave...? I like MATLAB way better!

Comment: @StewieGriffin If matlab is outputting the same thing as wolfram is (like on the normal), then it should be the same output but with a minus sign in the middle. I'm away from my PC so I can't check.

Answer (score 1):

### [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54720#54720)

### CJam, 9 bytes

Attempt 3...

```
Ps"."-i2b
```

Try the code at [this *correct* link.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Ps%22.%22-i2b)

### Expected output

```
1011001010010100001100001010001001010110110100100001
```

### Modified output

```
5010670554118
```

Another easy one??

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54720)

Answer (score 1):

### [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54737/43035)

## Perl, 48 bytes

### Code

```
$_=cos 99;printf"%.14f",0x7275*sin $_/s/[3-8]/0/
```

### Original Output

```
287.75699066847318
```

### Changed Output

```
144.01504526079819
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54737)

Comment: crap, that wasn't my solution (though it does work) ... I thought I proofed against that.  I had to make some last min changes to hit a proper levenshtein distance.  Am I allowed to revise?

Comment: Editing code in a cops-and-robbers post (especially when cracked) is not allowed, but you can always post a new answer.

Comment: nm, cat's out of the bag.  accepting.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54751)

## Python 3, 57 bytes

### Code:

```
import math, decimal
print(decimal.Decimal(math.tan(749)))
```

### Output:

```
3.615402552802641888973766981507651507854461669921875
```

### Changed Output:

```
0.6610431688506868130872362598893232643604278564453125
```

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54751)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54793)

## APL, 4

### Code

```
9⍟99
```

### Original Output

```
2.091329169322069
```

### Changed output

```
0.11111111111111112
```

[Tested here.](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=9%u235F99) Note that the last digit is 2. I just wanted to know how hard is an average APL submission.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54793)

Answer (score 0):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54696/30525)

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
.!77
```

### Output:

```
145183092028285869634070784086308284983740379224208358846781574688061991349156420080065207861248000000000000000000
```

### Changed Output:

```
3628800
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54696/20080)

Answer (score 0):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers/54718#54718)

## Python 2, 86 Bytes

## Original Code

```
import dis
def torun():
 print "hello world"
try:
 print dis.dis(torun)
except:
 pass
```

## Original Output:

```
 47           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello world')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE        
None
```

## Changed Output:

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: In Python 3, those print statements will cause syntax errors.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54718)

Comment: Good job. At least I learned how to use dis in the process of making this one.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 82 bytes

```
b=64,i,x[64];main(){for(i=b;i--;)x[(i*3)%b]^=x[(i*5)%b]+i,printf("%02u",x[--b]);}
```

Output 1:

> 00006362616059585756555453525150494847464544434241403938373635343332313029282726252423222120191817161514131211100908070605040100

Output 2:

> 000000006312518624630536342047653158563869074179184088893598110261070111311551196123612751313135013861421145514881520155115811610163816651691171617401763178518061826184518631880189619111925193819501961197119801988222001201400

Answer (score 0):

## JS,

```
Math.pow(2,10)
```

Original output:

```
1024
```

Changed output:

```
7.61773480458663923e+85
```

Has a Levenstein distance of 23(!).