# Two Makes All The Difference - Robbers

Tags: cops-and-robbers

## For the main cops' challenge, [click here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54464)

> **NOTICE** - This challenge is now closed. Any cracks which are posted now will not be counted on the leaderboard and the accepted answer will *not* change.

### Challenge

Given the original program, its output and the output of the changed program, you have to find out which characters need to be changed, removed or added to get the expected output.

When you crack someone's code, leave a comment with a link to your crack on their answer.

### Formatting

```
# [<language>, <username of program owner>](<link to answer>)

## Description

<description of change and how you found it>

## Code

<changed code>
```

### Winning

The person who has cracked the most solutions wins.

### Leaderboard

#### 13 cracks:

- Dennis

#### 8 cracks:

- Alex Van Liew

#### 5 cracks:

- Sp3000
- isaacg

#### 3 cracks:

- Luis Mendo
- jimmy23013
- Dom Hastings

#### 2 cracks:

- mbomb007
- Sluck49

#### 1 crack:

- TheNumberOne
- Jakube
- ProudHaskeller
- David Zhang
- samgak
- paul.oderso
- rayryeng
- mgibsonbr
- n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳
- Stewie Griffin
- abligh

Comment: @mbomb007 Can you refrain from editing this post, because it makes it harder for me to know where I am when updating the leaderboard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [CJam, by Mauris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54499)

#### Description

Mauris' original code does the following:

```
"f~"     e# Push that string on the stack.
    :i   e# Cast each to integer. Pushes [102 126].
      :# e# Reduce by exponentiation. Pushes 102^126.
```

No other of CJam's mathematical operators would yield a number that large for small inputs, so `:#` cannot be modified. Since `#`, when used for exponentiation, only takes integers as input, `:i` cannot be removed as well. This leaves only one place to modify the input: the string `"f~"`.

No matter how many characters the string holds, the result will be a left-associative power tower. CJam supports characters in the range from 0 to 65535 (with the exception of surrogates), so we have to express the output as **b<sup>n×k×j</sup>**, where **b**, **n**, **k** and **j** are integers in that range.

The decimal logarithm of the integer that results from the modified code is slightly smaller than **log<sub>10</sub>(2.44×10<sup>242545</sup>) = log<sub>10</sub>(2.44) + 242545**, so we can divide this value by the logarithms of all possible bases to find proper values for **n×k×j**.

In fact:

```
$ cjam <(echo '65536,2>{2.44AmL242545+1$AmL/i:I#s8<"24399707"=}=SIN')
5 347004
```

Comparing the first 8 digits turned out to be sufficient.

This means that we can express the output as **5<sup>347,004</sup> = 15625<sup>57,834</sup> = 125<sup>9×102×126</sup>**, so it suffices to **replace `"f~"` with `"㴉"` or `"}  f~"`**.

#### Code

```
"㴉":i:#
```

or

```
"}  f~":i:#
```

Note that the spaces in the ASCII code should actually be a tabulator.

Attempting to execute this code in the online interpreter is probably a bad idea, but here's how you can verify the results from the command line:

```
$ wget -q https://bpaste.net/raw/f449928d9870
$ cjam <(echo '[15625 57834]:c`":i:#") > mauris.cjam
$ cat mauris.cjam; echo
"㴉":i:#
$ cjam mauris.cjam | diff -s - f449928d9870
Files - and f449928d9870 are identical
$ echo -en '"}\tf~":i:#' > mauris-ascii.cjam
$ cat mauris.cjam; echo
"}  f~":i:#
$ cjam mauris-ascii.cjam | diff -s - f449928d9870
Files - and f449928d9870 are identical
```

Comment: One does not simply beat Dennis in CJam

Comment: How did you figure out what numbers to use?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew Brute force. I'm currently writing an explanation. I just wanted to get the crack posted before somebody else did.

Comment: @Dennis: Fair enough. I was trying this one but I don't know CJam; I figured the intended solution involved actually using `~f` somewhere in the program.

Comment: I hadn't really accounted for Unicode characters -- the PPCG tradition seems to be to count bytes, not characters. As such, there's a solution that doesn't use any. I suppose this counts, though? I'll let the OP decide.

Comment: @Mauris The question says *when just two **characters** in the program are changed* (emphasis mine), so I assumed this was OK. Anyway, factorizing the number was the hard part.

Comment: Hooray, you found it! Very nice job.

Comment: @AlexVanLiew I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Dennis: Very cool.

Answer (score 15):

## [Ruby, histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54507/16941)

### Description

Changed x to be an array instead of scalar by adding `*`

Changed the last `9` to be a string instead of a number by adding `?`

The result is made of an array with a single element (`[9]`) multipled 9 times then imploded with `"9"` as separator.

### Code

```
x=*9;puts x*9*?9
```

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2, muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54475/20080)

### Description

Through trials and tribulations involving factorizing large numbers and looking for consequtive factors, I realized that changing the 87654 to 58116 would be enough. Then, I factorized 58116 as 87*668. Then I realised that 01234 = 668, so I just needed to change 87654 to 87 and remove the 01234 entirely. This is accomplished with a comment.

### Code

```pyth
print (sum(range(054321)*9876)*87)#654)/01234
```

Comment: Yep, almost exactly how I had it (Mine was `print sum(range(054321)*9876)*87#654)/01234`)

Comment: Clever clever! I'm glad someone got it, and that it was more interesting than "play with numbers"!

Answer (score 11):

## [Shakespeare, AboveFire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54592/6741)

In Scene III, one has to change Claudius into Claudio in the following snippet:

```
[Enter Claudio]

Claudius:
 Thou art as stupid as the sum of thee and the product of the 
 product of me and Helen and Helena

[Exeunt]
```

### Modified code:

```
The Hidden Change.

Helen, a young woman with a remarkable patience.
Helena, a likewise young woman of remarkable grace.
Claudio, a remarkable man much in dispute with Claudius.
Claudius, the flatterer.
The Archbishop of Canterbury, the useless.


          Act I: Claudius's insults and flattery.

          Scene I: The insulting of Helen.

[Enter Claudius and Helen]

Claudius:
 Thou art as hairy as the sum of a disgusting horrible fatherless 
 dusty old rotten fat-kidneyed cat and a big dirty cursed war.
 Thou art as stupid as the product of thee and a fat smelly 
 half-witted dirty miserable vile weak son.

[Exeunt]

          Scene II: The complimenting of Helena.

[Enter Claudio and Helena]

Claudio:
 Thou art the sunny amazing proud healthy peaceful sweet joy.
 Thou art as amazing as the product of thee and the pretty
 lovely young gentle handsome rich Hero. Thou art as great 
 as the sum of thee and the product of a fair golden prompt good honest 
 charming loving noble king and a embroidered rich smooth golden angel.

[Exeunt]

          Scene III: The insulting of Claudio

[Enter Claudius and Helen]

Helen:
 Thou art as stupid as the sum of the sum of thee and a cat and me.
[Exit Helen]

[Enter Claudio]

Claudio:
 Thou art as stupid as the sum of thee and the product of the 
 product of me and Helen and Helena

[Exeunt]

          Scene IV: The Final Countdown

[Enter The Archbishop of Canterbury and Claudius]

Claudius:
 Thou art the sum of you and a cat.

The Archbishop of Canterbury:
 Am I better than a fine road?

Claudius:
 If not, let us return to the insulting of Claudio.

[Exit The Archbishop of Canterbury]

[Enter Claudio]

Claudius:
 Open your heart!
 Open your heart!
[Exeunt]
```

Using the compiler linked by @AboveFire, this prints `11`.

Comment: Can you please make it more clear which characters were changed? It's not exactly easy to see looking back and forth.

Comment: Damn, 15 minutes late. Congratulations.

Comment: Jeebus H. Christ. Nice job!

Comment: I figured it had to be something like that; it seemed unlikely (and downright cruel) to make the two characters in a noun or adjective somewhere. Somehow, though, I think the poeticism is much better in the original...

Comment: I am damn sad :'( I put the names of the variables similar to lead you on a wrong track. I was sure I made it so it was only possible in the way I designed it, but you found another way... Well you got it xD I confirm that you cracked the code successfully.

Comment: @mbomb007 I hope my edit made it clearer. AboveFire: sorry :)

Comment: @plannapus Haha, it's okay, but the intended way to clear it was to replace the word "king" by "pig".With this change, Helena was equal to 0 and "the sum of thee and the product of the product of me and Helen and Helena" was equal to 1. I had made a list of all words that could be inverted with two letters and used a lot of them in my code(ex: joy->hog->son, war->cat, road->toad, Hero->Hell, curse->purse, helen->helena, claudio->claudius and many others) The only things that can change a Shakespeare program with 2 char is the change of a variable, the change of a noun and the change of a goto.

Comment: That was way trickier indeed :)

Comment: Good work.
its nice to see I too was on the right track when i gave it a try :) - again, good work @plannapus

Answer (score 10):

## [Prolog, Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54487/21487)

### Description

Add two `\`s. `\` is bitwise negation and `\/` is bitwise or.

### Code

```
X is \1\/42.
```

Comment: Correct solution

Answer (score 8):

### [MATLAB/OCTAVE, Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54549/21654)

A simple bit of complex arithmetic.

```
acos(i)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [C, LambdaBeta](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54482/29577)

### Description

Turn `main(a,_)` into `main(_)`. The first argument of main is `argc` which is initialized as `1`.

### Code

```
main(_){puts(_*_-1||_*_*_-1||_*_*_*_-1?"Expected Output":"?");}
```

Comment: That's the solution I had in mind. Nice catch. Incidentally if the argv happens to be loaded into memory cell 1 this will not work. I just can't think of any system that would do that that can also run the various interpreted languages on that page.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2, rp.belrann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54608/19349)

Change the outermost list comprehension into a set comprehension. Partial credit to @mbomb007, who eliminated all of the "boring" solutions (swapping `x` and `y` around, tweaking operators, changing the range).

```
'~'*sum({(x,y)[x%2] for x in[y for y in range(8)]})
```

#### Explanation:

In the original, `[(x,y)[x%2]for x in[y for y in range(8)]]` generates the following list:

```
[0, 7, 2, 7, 4, 7, 6, 7]
```

This is because in Python 2.7, the `y` in the inner list comprehension *leaks* into the enclosing scope at it's last known value (which, at the end of a range, is 7). So, in the tuple, `y` is always 7. `x`, however, goes through the list as normal, ranging from 0 to 7. When `x` is even, it chooses the value of `x`, when it's odd, it chooses `y` (which is always 7). I noticed that if I included exactly one 7 and all the rest of the values of `x`, I got 19; then I realized that I could transform the outer comprehension into a set comprehension, which would eliminate all duplicate values and leave me with exactly 19.

This was pretty clever, I don't think I've ever used a set comprehension before. Kudos.

Comment: nope. That's not it. `print len('~'*sum([(x,y)[x%2]for x in[y for y in range(6)]]))` returns `21`. Just assign the code to a variable then print if it equals the string you want. If you see `True`, you cracked it.

Comment: Bizarre. `_` betrayed me, I guess.

Comment: @mbomb007 I got it.

Comment: You got me. Well done.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jonas, Matlab/Octave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54654/20080)

### Description

I noticed the answer was `i^pi`, so then I justed had to turn `sin` into a nop.

### Code

```
0i+(i^pi)
```

`s` -> `0`, `n` -> `+`

Comment: Nicely done sir.

Comment: Very well done!!

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash, Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54524/42620)

Original code:

```
echo {{{1..9}}}
```

Original output:

```
{{1}} {{2}} {{3}} {{4}} {{5}} {{6}} {{7}} {{8}} {{9}}
```

Modified code:

```
echo {,{1..9},}
```

Modified output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Explanation:

In Bash you can output a comma separated list of items inside a pair of braces, like this:

```
echo {a,b,c}
```

prints

```
a b c
```

So the modified code is printing out a list of nothing, the numbers 1..9, nothing.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATLAB, Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54593/31516)

Original code:

```
-sin(2:.5:3)    
ans =    
   -0.9093   -0.5985   -0.1411
```

New answer:

```
psi(2:.5:3)
ans =
    0.4228    0.7032    0.9228
```

## Description:

Changed `-sin` to `psi`, the polygamma function in MATLAB. The `-` sign is substituted by `p` and the `n` is removed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brainfuck, Kurousagi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54478/21487)

### Description

Remove the first `>` and change the first `<` to `.`

Tested at [brainfuck.tk](http://brainfuck.tk/). Note that the output doesn't match Kurousagi's post *exactly*, due to SE eating up unprintable characters.

### Code

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[>.+<-]
```

Comment: @muddyfish I linked this answer in my second comment, but I'm still awaiting confirmation from Kurousagi

Answer (score 4):

## [C, LambdaBeta](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54482/29577)

### Description

Change `-1` into `*0` so that the result of the multiplication is `0` (a falsy value).

### Code

```
main(a,_){puts(_*_*_*_*_*0?"Expected Output":"?");}
```

Comment: Oops, looks like I introduced a (security flaw?) during my golfing. I'll idly mull it over to see if I can fix it. Nice catch though.

Answer (score 4):

## [Fantom, Cain](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54506/19349)

Security through obscurity is a very poor form of security (especially when the two methods are right next to each other in the Fantom docs and anyone who knows what a float looks like will immediately know what to do).

```
Float.makeBits32(1123581321)
```

Comment: You got me by 1 min !!! well played

Comment: Haha you got me, enjoy the free crack

Comment: @Cain Was that intentional o.o

Comment: @BassetHound I mean, it was more of a social experiment, to see if people would bother learning some obscure language for the crack. I should have made it harder though, to take some actual work.

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam, by Basset Hound](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54520)

```
25me
```

Calculates **e<sup>25</sup>**. [Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=25me)

The online interpreter gives a slightly different result in my browser, which seems to be a rounding issue.

The Java interpreter prints `7.200489933738588E10`, which is the desired output, but in a different format.

Comment: Hehe, it was easy. Especially for a CJam god. Correct.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2, Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54541/25180)

### Description

Changed `01234` to `0x1234` and `min` to `9in`.

The fact that `4669 = (01234-1)*sum(m<<m in R for m in R)` is misleading.

### Code

```python
R=range(0x1234);print sum(m<<9in(m,n)for m in R for n in R)
```

Comment: Nicely done! I had `m<<m in(m,n)`, but the main thing was to change the `min` to `in`.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATLAB / Octave, Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54569/42418)

### Description

This required negating the input into the anonymous function `g`, as well as changing the scaling factor of the `g` function to 2 instead of 7:

### Code

```
>> f=@(x)x^.7;g=@(x)2/f(x);g(-7)

ans =

  -0.3011 - 0.4144i
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my (now deleted) answer. I posted a new (very similar) one that can be cracked using WolframAlpha. I believe it's fairer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl, abligh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54596/21487)

### Description

Add in string repetition operator, `x` and insert additional digit!

### Code

```pl
print sin 95x7
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Java, TheNumberOne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54490/19349)

### Description

The program is a one-off implementation of [`Random.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed(long)) with a initial seed of `Integer.MAX_INT` and all the hex numbers converted to decimal. Changing the seed to the complement of `MAX_INT` generates the output:

```
class T{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(((~Integer.MAX_VALUE^25214903917L)&281474976710655L)*25214903917L+11L&281474976710655L);}}
```

(since there must be exactly two changes, pick any sort of no-op change: adding a space somewhere, an extra semicolon, etc)

Comment: Nice, You could have also turned `Integer.MAX_VALUE` into `Integer.MAX_VALUE+1` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: Oh, you know what? I tried `+1` but since I was doing it in Python it just rolled over to a long, ahaha. That was my first thought, actually.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brainfuck, AboveFire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54476/20370)

this program is a modification of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54427/20370) code me a cookie answer.
that answer works by first pre-calculating a table of useful ascii codes of useful characters, and then has three conditional statements made up by three loops which are entered to by having a `1` in the correct position.

the start of how i broke the code is that the repeating pattern in the changed output is mostly what is printed if you enter the third loop with the table shifted left.

```
++++++++++[->++++++++<]>>++++++[-<---------->]<-------[----------->>>-<<+<[->->+<<]]>>>+<<>>>+++[->++++++++++<]>(<)++ .<+++++++++[->>>>>>>++++++++++<+++++<++++++++++++++<++++++++++<+++++<++++++++++<<]++++++++++>>+++++...>++>++>-->+>(>)++++<<<<<<<.<<<[->>>>>>.<<>>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<<>>>.<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<...>.<<<<<<]>[->>>>>.<<...>>>.<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<...>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<...>.<<<<<]>[->>>>.<<>>>>>>.<<<<<<..>>>.<<<<.>>>>>.<<<<>>>>>>.<<<<<<.>>>>>>.<<<<<<>>>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<...>.<<<<]
```

(the additional characters are marked with parentheses)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2, muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54551/21487)

### Description

Change `<<` to `<>` (deprecated version of `!=`) and `0x156` to `0156`, the code point for `"n"` (which appears 3 times in the length 23 string `'<built-in function sum>'`).

### Code

```py
print sum((ord(i)<>0156 for i in `sum`))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript, by Razvan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54562)

#### Description

The modified output is clearly Euler's natural number, which can be accessed as `Math['E']`.

By changing `''` to `'3'` and `32` to `36`, `String.fromCharCode` generates the `E`.

#### Code

```
a=1,b=a*2,c=a+b,d=[a+b];while(c>b)c-=a;for(i=1;i<=c;i++)d.push(i);i='3'+c*d['length']*d['length'];alert(Math[String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt(0) * i.charCodeAt(1) / 36)])
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Still it was actually something deeper but it seems that you could bypass it with this trick. I'll think of something else and I'll come back.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fantom, Cain](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54598/20080)

### Description

The array indexing is set up already, so I just need to make a 55. Honestly, the hardest part was downloading the language.

### Code

```
[7115432d/9,219.or(64),37,55,55][3]
```

(Inserted a comma, `0` -> `3`)

Comment: Well crap, that wasn't the intended solution, my red herring was an actual solution

Answer (score 3):

## [Shakespeare, AboveFire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54592/42503)

## NOT CORRECT - sorry :(

Will look further into it when i get home from work
In the original Claudio's value is 1132462081
and Claudius' value is 1

In the final Scene Claudio's value is printed twice,

```
[Enter Claudio]

Claudius:
 Open your heart!
 Open your heart!
```

open your heart x2 = print value of the other person on stage (Claudio).
So if you change Claudius to Claudio(2 chars) - the value of Claudius will be printed - which is 1 - twice

```
The Hidden Change.

Helen, a young woman with a remarkable patience.
Helena, a likewise young woman of remarkable grace.
Claudio, a remarkable man much in dispute with Claudius.
Claudius, the flatterer.
The Archbishop of Canterbury, the useless.


          Act I: Claudius's insults and flattery.

          Scene I: The insulting of Helen.

[Enter Claudius and Helen]

Claudius:
 Thou art as hairy as the sum of a disgusting horrible fatherless 
 dusty old rotten fat-kidneyed cat and a big dirty cursed war.
 Thou art as stupid as the product of thee and a fat smelly 
 half-witted dirty miserable vile weak son.

[Exeunt]

          Scene II: The complimenting of Helena.

[Enter Claudio and Helena]

Claudio:
 Thou art the sunny amazing proud healthy peaceful sweet joy.
 Thou art as amazing as the product of thee and the pretty
 lovely young gentle handsome rich Hero. Thou art as great 
 as the sum of thee and the product of a fair golden prompt good honest 
 charming loving noble king and a embroidered rich smooth golden angel.

[Exeunt]

          Scene III: The insulting of Claudio

[Enter Claudius and Helen]

Helen:
 Thou art as stupid as the sum of the sum of thee and a cat and me.
[Exit Helen]

[Enter Claudio]

Claudius:
 Thou art as stupid as the sum of thee and the product of the 
 product of me and Helen and Helena

[Exeunt]

          Scene IV: The Final Countdown

[Enter The Archbishop of Canterbury and Claudius]

Claudius:
 Thou art the sum of you and a cat.

The Archbishop of Canterbury:
 Am I better than a fine road?

Claudius:
 If not, let us return to the insulting of Claudio.

[Exit The Archbishop of Canterbury]

[Enter Claudio]

Claudio: << changed Claudius to Claudio
 Open your heart!
 Open your heart!
[Exeunt]
```

Comment: Nope, Claudio value is not 1 xD. Better luck next time.

Comment: @AboveFire - crud.. I'll have another look at it when i get home, really thought I had it :(

Comment: That was my first guess, too, but I didn't have a chance to try it, yet. Anyway, the only part I didn't understand yet is the one with the archbishop so I'll have a look at that when I get home.

Answer (score 3):

## [Matlab / Octave, Jonas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54625/36398)

### Description

In the last line, add `'` to transform `arg'` into the string `'arg'`, which will then be interpreted as ASCII numbers. And then add another `'` at the end to maintain the column format.

The almost unnecessary `'` in the original code was the main clue. Also, in restrospect, the fact that `arg` was defined separately (instead of directly within the `sin` line) should have looked suspicious.

### Code

```
format long
arg = [.1 .2 .3];
sin('arg'*exp(9))'
```

Answer (score 3):

## [VBA by JimmyJazzx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54511/34718)

Changed `IRR` to `MIRR` and changed `5` to a `,` so there are 3 parameters.

I found this while looking for how Excel's `IRR` function works. There was an article: [How Excel's MIRR Function Can Fix the IRR Function](http://exceluser.com/formulas/irr.htm). That tipped me off. Clever attempt, though. I'd never used VBA before, so that was interesting as well.

```
Sub q()
Dim a(2) As Double
a(0)=-5
a(1)=10
msgBox MIRR(a,0.2,3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. Technically i added both the M and the , so the middle arg was 0.25 but i think they end up having the same result anyway.    Thought using some finance functions could stump the programmers but was revealed by the documentation. Good job

Answer (score 3):

## [bc, abligh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54591/34718)

Merely inserted the math operators. Took about 1 minute to solve once I looked up what bc was and what math operations it had. The first thing I thought of was division, but there weren't common factors that looked nice. So I immediately went for exponentiation and modulus. At least 15 digits were necessary for the modulus b/c of the expected output. After that, I guessed twice and found it.

```
4518^574%615489737231532
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua, TreFox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54595/43004)

### Description

"_G" is the global table, making "_G.load" refer to the global function "load". Converting a function to a string results in returning the function's address, which is then made into the length of the string by the length-operator "#".

### Code

```
G={load="lfkjgGsHjkU83fy6dtrg"}
print(#tostring(_G.load))
```

Also, since this is my first post on here, I can't make a comment on the original answer.

Comment: I've left a comment on the cop answer. By the way, this doesn't quite work for me. The address is I get is `0x321a40c6d0`, for a final output of `22`.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting 22... on everything  I tested it was 18 or 26.

Comment: @Dennis Try it [in the official lua demo.](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)

Comment: Aha, I was so close! I knew I needed the global `load`, and I knew `_G` referred to the global symbol table... I just didn't put the two together.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python, rp.beltran](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54694/20080)

### Description

I noticed that the needed letters were always 2 in front of a digit. changing the third `\w` to `\d` got all of the right letters except the spaces. `\D` was the only `\` group I could find that allowed letters and spaces.

### Code

```
import re;''.join(re.findall('\D(?=\w\d)','t74q joh7 jv f9dfij9j bfjtf0e nnjen3j nnjrb6fgam3gtm5tem3hj s3eim7djsd3ye d5dfhg5un7ljmm8nan3nn6n k m2ftm5bsof5bf r5arm4ken8 adcm3nub0 nfrn6sn3jfeb6n d m6jda5 gdif5vh6 gij7fnb2eb0g '))
```

`w` -> `D`, `w` -> `d` in the regex.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth, isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54529)

#### Description

The original code does the following:

```
 CG      Convert "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" from base 256 to integer, yielding
         156490583352162063278528710879425690470022892627113539022649722.
   ^3y21 Compute 3^(2 * 21).
%        Calculate the modulus.
```

Since **156490583352162063278528710879425690470022892627113539022649722 - 58227066** gives **156490583352162063278528710879425690470022892627113538964422656**, which equals **2<sup>26</sup> × 3 × 7 × 7477 × 381524422711 × 17007550201751761 × 2288745700077000184147**, the desired output can be obtained by replacing `^3y21` with something that evaluates to a divisor of this product and is larger than **58227066**.

The `^` in the original code suggests that we might use it to calculate a power of **2**, the **3** that we could calculate a fitting divisor of the form **3 × 2<sup>n</sup>**.

Both are misleading. Solutions with a Levenshtein distance of 3 (`%CG^2 26`, `%CG^y2 13`, `%CG^4y13`) or 4 (`%CG.<3y13`) are readily found, but the solution at distance 2 requires a different approach.

The lowercase alphabet (`G`) has 26 letters, so its power set (the set of all strictly increasing sequences of lowercase letters) has **2<sup>26</sup>** elements. By **replacing `y2` with `yG`**, we compute this power set.

We can retrieve the set's length by **replacing `3` with `l`**, which leaves us with `^lyG1`, i.e., **2<sup>26</sup>** raised to the first power.

#### Code

```
%CG^lyG1
```

Note that this will only work on a computer with enough available memory (roughly 6.43 GiB, according to `time`), so it will not work with the online interpreter.

Here's how you can verify the results from the command line:

```
$ \time -v pyth -c '%CG^lyG1'
58227066
        Command being timed: "pyth/pyth.py -c %CG^lyG1"
        User time (seconds): 30.73
        System time (seconds): 2.12
        Percent of CPU this job got: 100%
        Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:32.85
        Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
        Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
        Average stack size (kbytes): 0
        Average total size (kbytes): 0
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 6742564
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
        Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
        Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 2269338
        Voluntary context switches: 1
        Involuntary context switches: 58
        Swaps: 0
        File system inputs: 0
        File system outputs: 0
        Socket messages sent: 0
        Socket messages received: 0
        Signals delivered: 0
        Page size (bytes): 4096
        Exit status: 0
```

Comment: Correct! Well done.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL, Mauris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54683)

#### Description

This was pretty much trial and error. I knew I had to insert a `¯` (negative number) and use mathematical functions like `○` (trigonometic) or `⍟` (logarithm) that yield complex number for negative input, or directly insert a `J` (imaginary part).

After *a lot* or errors, I finally tried **inserting a `¯` before `7` and a `⍟` before `/`**.

#### Code

```
-⍟/3⍴15¯7
```

Try it online in [ngn/apl demo](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=-%u235F/3%u237415%AF7), the online interpreter recommended by the cop.

Note that this won't work in, e.g., Dyalog APL, which requires a space before the high minus.

Comment: Wow, you just don't stop! :O

Answer (score 3):

## [APL, Mauris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54773)

#### Description

Unlike the two APL answers I cracked before, the indented output of this one reveals very little about the required changes, so I decided to try a brute force approach.

Two characters aren't enough for loops, so the added characters (if any) had to be parts of numeric literals, mathematical functions or `⍨`.

I chose a subset and hoped I'd get lucky. Using [this CJam script](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%3AC%2C2*)%3AL_)*lN%2B%3AM%2C_**%7BM%2CmdM%3D%3AX%3BM%2CmdM%3D%3AY%3BLmdCLQa*.%5C%5CXtsL)Qa*.%5C%5CYtsN-%7D%2F%5D%7BW%3DA%2Cs%26%7D%2CQ%7CN*&input=3%E2%8D%9F877%0A0123456789.%C2%AF%2B-%C3%B7%C3%97%E2%8C%88%E2%8C%8A*!%7C%E2%8D%9F%E2%97%8B%E2%8A%A5%E2%8A%A4%E2%8D%A8), I generated all source codes (many of them with syntax errors) at an edit distance of 2 or less that only add character from the chosen set. This yielded 28,014 different potential solutions.

Aside from the online interpreter, [ngn/apl](https://github.com/ngn/apl#readme) is available for NodeJS. It even has a command-line flag (`-l`) that executes code linewise, which is almost perfect for this purpose.

After a minor change that condensed error output to a single line, I was able to grep the output to find the line number of the correct source code. The interpreter powered through the roughly 28,000 possible solutions in less than 6 seconds.

This sums up what I did:

```
$ diff apl.js `which ngn-apl`
4806c4806
<                       return e + '\n';
---
>                       return ('' + e).replace(/\n/g, '') + '\n';
$ cjam gen-edit-dist-2.cjam > brute-force.apl
3⍟877
0123456789.¯+-÷×⌈⌊*!|⍟○⊥⊤⍨
$ wc -l brute-force.apl 
28014 brute-force.apl
$ time ngn-apl -l < brute-force.apl | grep -n '0\.2001649'
3791:0.20016493054644696
20128:0.20016493054644696

real    0m5.506s
user    0m5.516s
sys     0m0.252s
÷3⍟○77
3⍟⍨○77
```

This reveals two possible solutions: **replacing `8` with `○` and inserting `÷` before `3`**, or **replacing `8` with `⍨○`**.

#### Code

```
÷3⍟○77
```

or

```
3⍟⍨○77
```

Try them online in the [ngn/apl demo](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%F73%u235F%u25CB77).<sup>1</sup>

These modifications calculate **1 / log<sub>3</sub> 77π = log<sub>77π</sub> 3**, which yields the desired output.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that the last digit may be a `3` on some machines.</sub>

Comment: Nice work. But if the digits change from browser to browser that is a *huge* problem... Maybe jimmy23013's 4 byte APL cop is impossible in some environments simply depending on floating point rounding

Comment: This seems to be a simple 32 vs 64 bit issue. jimmy23013's modified code works on my desktop and my phone, so it doesn't seem to have the same issue. Writing truly platform-independent code should pretty much be impossiboe once you involve fixed width floats...

Answer (score 2):

## [C++, f41lurizer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54517/19349)

Good old trigraphs.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    //can you figure it out??/
    std::cout << "I like cake and";
}
```

Comment: `g++` won't accept the trigraph without additional compiler flags. Removing the newline should work with all compilers.

Comment: Heh, I suppose that does work, huh? I'm pretty sure this was the intended solution, but it doesn't really matter since the original is invalid anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2, muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54540/21487)

### Description

Change `` `i` `` to `` `id` = '<built-in function id>' `` and `1234` to `01234` (octal). Found by recalling the wise words of Sir @xnor (paraphrased): "If you ever need a string that's 22 chars long..."

### Code

```py
i=long;j=map;print reduce(i.__mul__,j(i,j(ord,`id`)))/01234
```

Answer (score 2):

## [VBA, JimmyJazzx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54511/42978)

### Description

First of all the call of `a(2)` was strange since only `a(0)` and `a(1)` get used, that was actually a big hint.

Next i looked into what the function IRR really does [(see here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return.).
There is no combination of integer `a(0)` and `a(1)` that can possibly yield the modified output.

So I looked for combinations of `a(0)` and `a(2)` (<- first character changed) that resulted in the desired output and found `a(0) = -1` and `a(2) = 8`. Since multiplying `a(0)` and `a(2)` with the same number doesn't change the outcome I simply multiplied both with 5 so `a(0)` would stay the same.

### Code

```
Sub q()
Dim a(2) As Double
a(0) = -5
a(2) = 40
MsgBox IRR(a, 0.253)
End Sub
```

Comment: Though this may yeild the correct result this is not what I had done. mbomb007 did get what i had done correct. 

Good try though and im not sure which one the judge will accept as this one did come in first and ends up with the same result as the real answer.

As for the a(2) that was there to mislead people, as it took the same amount of bytes as a(1) would have. But wanted to keep people away from seeing what IRR really does.

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure, Bob Jarvis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54570/19349)

Base conversions are fun.

```
(printf "%d\n" 7r2155263413256326162)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP, Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54586/19349)

```
print_r(range(1,07));
```

I guess it really was that simple.

Comment: Yup, it was that simple. I didn't put that much effort on it, I was just warming up.

Comment: PHP could be a great language for this challenge because of all the wonky stuff it's got in there.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will come up with something

Answer (score 2):

## [modern Perl 5, msh210](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54587/20080)

### Description

The `s///` call has to only apply to the first element in the `@array` and using `each` with the `for` covers it off!

### Code

```pl
@array = (qw smiles) x 11;
s/.*// for each @array;
print "@array\n";
```

Added space in between `for` and `each`. I

Comment: Works in [ideone](http://ideone.com/hOhJ9s). You can just add an arbitrary space for the second changed character.

Answer (score 2):

## [Matlab/Octave, paul.oderso](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54610/20080)

### Description

I took the natural log, and recognized it as near pi ^ 2. From there it was easy.

### Code

```
e^(pi*pi)+2
```

Added a `p`, `1` -> `2`

Answer (score 2):

## [MATLAB, Jonas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54620/21487)

### Description

Change `1+1` to `49+1`. I don't actually have MATLAB so I can't test this, but the number looks right

### Code

```
sin(49+1)
```

Comment: yes - thought that's not what I had in mind.

Comment: @Jonas: What was the hard solution? Do you mind sharing?

Comment: @StewieGriffin: Here's a better version of the question instead: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54625/18

Answer (score 2):

## [Matlab / Octave, Jonas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54618/36398)

### Description

Just change `tragic` by `magic` in the second line.

`tragic` is a symmetric, integer-valued matrix. The difference between both inputs is integer-valued but not symmetric. So a new kind of matrix was needed. The integer values and the name `traffic` looked [familiar](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/magic.html).

### Code

```
mistake=-1;tragic=rosser;a=hilb(8)*42;
a(:,:)+magic(8)/mistake
```

Comment: I guess I should have put a call to `det` in there to make it harder, but I wanted this to remain fun (also, `det` doesn't easily fit into a sentence)

Comment: A [magic mistake](http://catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html), eh?

Comment: @Jonas Yes, with `det` it would have been much harder

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language Mathematica or WolframAlpha, belisarius](/a/54642)

### Original Code

```
8.!
```

### Changed Code

```
8.^i!
```

### Original Output

```
40320.
```

### Changed output

```
2.67182 - 0.891969 I
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript, Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54659/25180)

### Description

`9,:n9` doesn't work because `n9` would be one variable name. In GolfScript you usually get rid of this by using a symbol as the variable name, so...

### Code

```
9,: 9
```

[More explanations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5266/25180).

Comment: Did... Did you assign something to the space character?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew Yes. The full program executed would be ``9,:space 9]print space n space print``.

Comment: That's amazing.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript, Razvan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54629/25180)

### Description

Changed `1` to `.1` and added a semicolon.

### Code

```
a=(((b=(a=.1)+a)+a)-b-a)*(a=[b]);['length'];
alert(a);
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP, Razvan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54706)

#### Description

Inserted `(` and `)`, so `$T_I_(M_E * $A_U_T_U_M_N)` executes `TAN(M_E * 2)`, where `M_E` is Euler's natural number.

#### Code

```
$S_U_M_M_E_R = 1;
$A_U_T_U_M_N = 2;
$T_I_M_E = 1;

if ($T_I_M_E == $S_U_M_M_E_R) {
    $A_C_=$T_I_=$O_N= 'SWIM' ? 'TAN' : 'DRINK';
}

print $T_I_(M_E * $A_U_T_U_M_N);
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby, histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54580)

### Description

Need to make the regex at the end work on the string literal `?9` so we need to make the variable `$_` instead of `_`, also need to start the regex itself. Didn't realise that you could omit the `{}` when interpolating variables into regex in ruby.

### Code

```rb
p $_=?9;p$.+=1until /#$./
```

Comment: Confirmed working on ideone (Ruby 2.1.5), but it doesn't work on my machine (Ruby 2.1.5). Odd.

Comment: Nice one. works fine for me in `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave, Daniel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54752)

#### Description

111 is the code point of the ASCII character **o**, so the desired output can be achieved by **replacing `cos` with `"o"`**.

`(1)` retrieves the first character of the string and `*1` casts to integer.

#### Code

```
format long;
"o"(1)*1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL, jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54789)

#### Description

The output is obviously **1/9** with rounding errors and the code already contains a `⍟` (logarithm), so using it together with `*` (exponentiation) seems a natural choice for introducing that error.

In fact, **inserting `⍨` between `⍟` and `9`, and `*` between `9` and `9`** produces the intended output.

`⍨` reverses the arguments of the preceding dyadic function, so this calculates **log<sub>9<sup>9</sup></sub>9 ≈ 1/9** with the intended error.

#### Code

```
9⍟⍨9*9
```

Try it online in the [ngn/apl demo](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=9%u235F%u23689*9).

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP, Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/two-makes-all-the-difference-robbers)

Comment out the first two lines so they all append together.

```
define('E','!');

$x = 4;
$t = " Hello World";
$t .= #;
$t .= #;
$t .= E;

print($t);
```

Comment: Not quite, I get: ` Hello World!tt`... UsingPHP 5.4 if that makes a difference... I'll update the other with the version.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua, TreFox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54561/19349)

In Lua, `#` is the "sizeof" operator. The discrepancy in the original behavior (15 or 23) is because the solution involves the size of the string created by converting a table to a string, and that string contains the address of the table (which is 16 characters on a 64-bit system and 8 on a 32-bit system). It looks like the particular distribution TreFox has is 64-bit. Also, apparently arguments in Lua work like arguments in Javascript, in which they don't seem to care how many arguments are passed, so changing the `.` to a `,` only causes `G` to be printed.

```lua
G={string="gs_hSDrGSFG5;U*ts"}
print(#tostring(G,string))
```

Secretly, I think this challenge was designed to make you think about skimpy underwear the whole time you were working on it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Matlab / Octave, rayryeng](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54578/36398)

### Description

Change `eig` to `eigs` and `sin` to `sind`.

The main clue was that the modified output has six eigenvalues sorted by magnitude, which is what `eigs` returns.

### Code

```
eigs(cov(reshape(sind(1:60),5,[])))
```

Comment: Very well done! How long did that take you to figure out? :)

Comment: It took quite a while... but I see now that the main clue had already been given in [Matlab's chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25056470#25056470) !

Answer (score 1):

## [SWI-Prolog, Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54516/7951)

### Description

Replace an `E` for an `F` (or the other way around) and change a single digit in one of the numbers input.

### Code

```
assert(d(F,F):-(print(E),print(F))). d(123456,123457).
```

Comment: That's not how I did it, but that works nonetheless! Well done. The way I did it was changing `d(123456,123456)` to `dif(123456,123456)`, to call the builtin predicate `dif/2` which returns false if its two arguments are the same.

Comment: @Fatalize I *really* wish I've seen this earlier :P

Answer (score 1):

## [SWI-Prolog, mgibsonbr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54607/6638)

### Description

Change `,` (conjunction) to `;` (disjunction).

Add a space to make the distance 2.

### Code

```
assert((o(X,Y,Z):-ABC is X**X; print(ABC))). o(99,y,z).
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript, Razvan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54619/32628)

### Description

The changed output being 10/3 was a dead giveaway.

### Code

```
one = 1;
two = one + one;
three = two + one;
zero = three - two - one;
numbers = [three, two, one];

for (i = numbers.length - 1; i <= zero; i--) {
    numbers.pop();
}

infinity = 10 / numbers['length'];
alert(infinity);
```

Comment: No worries - I had `==` in the `for` loop, but yeah `10/3` was a dead giveaway :)

Comment: Correct, I didn't notice this obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth, Beta Decay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54695/20080)

### Description

This one's just obvious.

### Code

```
.!10
```

`77` -> `10`

Comment: Actually, I went for `.!&77T`. I guess I didn't really give it much thought ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [CSS, Qwertiy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54698/32628)

### Description

After seeing that the first number was a zero what needed changed seemed pretty clear

### Code

```css
body:after{counter-reset:b 512;content:counter(a)"%"}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stuck, Vioz-](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54632/19349)

Change the first two numbers both to `3`.

```
3R3R3R4R5R6R7R8R9R9z]
```

Zipping in Stuck works like zipping in Python (I imagine `z` is backed by `zip()`), which is the shortest sequence is taken as the max length. Without the `]`, the output is a list of tuples, and I don't really know what `]` does. Pops the list at the top of the stack and pushes everything in it onto the stack, it looks like.

@Vioz-: Particularly for your `scipy` module, you should make sure that if the `numpy` or `scipy` libraries aren't available it doesn't crash with `ImportError`, but rather defines any methods that module supplies to just raise `NotImplementedError` or something similar. Also, you probably shouldn't commit `.pyc` files to your repo.

Comment: Nice! My solution was actually `12R3R4R5R6R7R8R9R8z]` (remove the first `R`, change the last `9` to `8`). I guess I didn't think of the obvious solution :P. Also, thanks for the tips, I'm sort of new to this whole "my own language thing". `]` just pops each element from the top list of the stack and adds it to the stack. I don't think I said that clearly in my explanation.

Comment: @Vioz- You'll get the hang of it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python, rp.beltran](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54717)

#### Description

Changed `dis` to `this`.

`import this` is an easter egg which prints [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

#### Code

```
import this
def torun():
 print "hello world"
try:
 print dis.dis(torun)
except:
 pass
```

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds.

Comment: Dang it. I was hoping that trick was more obscure. Good job.

Comment: @rp.beltran I mean, if you google "The zen of python"... A more obscure trick I saw in an old cops/robbers was using `from __future__ import braces` and some clever stuff to extract the string "chance".

Comment: Fair point, and I figured it would get cracked pretty quickly. 2 people in 4 minutes though, I'm impressed.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam, Basset Hound](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54716)

#### Description

Finding the proper changes is easier if we work from the desired output. `5010670554118` looks like an integer in base 8 or higher.

```
5010670554118Ab8b
S
5010670554118Ab9b
```

prints `344786655312 1415926558979`, and the second group of digits look a lot like the decimal expansion of Pi.

In fact, `Ps` pushes `"3.141592653589793"` (Pi cast to string), `"3."-` (**added `3`)** removes all occurrences of **3** and **.**, `i` converts the result to the integer `1415926558979` and `9b` (**replaced `2` with `9`**) performs the required base conversion.

#### Code

```
Ps"3."-i9b
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Ps%223.%22-i9b)

Comment: Yep, that's it...

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl, Adam Katz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54735)

#### Description

`$_=cos 99` saves **0.0398208803931389** in the variable `$_`. If we multiply this amount by **0x7275**, we obtain **1166.79161639936**, which is roughly 4 times the original output and 8 times the modified output.<sup>1</sup>

The original code archives *almost-division-by-4* by substituting *the first* **3** in `$_` with a **0** by executing `s/[3-8]/0/`, which modifies `$_` and returns the number of substitutions (1), by which `$_` is then divided.<sup>2</sup>

After noting that there are eight digits between **3** and **8** in the unmodified value of `$_`, attempting to replace all of them by **appending `g` to `s/[3-8]/0/`** seemed natural, since this will divide the (modified) value of `$_` by the number of substitutions.

Finally, to diminish the effect of the *almost-division-by-4*, it suffices to replace the first **3** (and all occurrences of **3** and **8** that follow) with a **3** by **replacing `s/[3-8]/0/` with `s/[3-8]/3/`**.

#### Code

```
$_=cos 99;printf"%.14f",0x7275*sin $_/s/[3-8]/3/g
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The code actually applies sine to `$_` before multiplying, but **sin x ≈ x** when **x** is close to **0**.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Again, this completely ignores the sine, which is almost linear near **0**.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [Python, Beta Decay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54748)

#### Description

Calling `math.tan` on the desired ouput gives **0.777…**, so it suffices to replace `tan` with `atan` and `749` with `7/9`.

#### Code

```
import math, decimal
print(decimal.Decimal(math.atan(7/9)))
```

The output is actually `0.66104316885068692410953872240497730672359466552734375` on my machine, which rounds the (intermediate) result of `math.atan(7/9)` differently.

Comment: Yep, you got it :D